# Apply CSS styles to an element depending on its child elements

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to define a CSS style for an element, that is only applied if the matching element contains a specific element (as the direct child item)?

I think this is best explained using an example.

**Note**: I'm trying to **style the parent element**, depending on what child elements it contains.

```
<style>
  /* note this is invalid syntax. I'm using the non-existing
   ":containing" pseudo-class to show what I want to achieve. */
  div:containing div.a { border: solid 3px red; }
  div:containing div.b { border: solid 3px blue; }
</style>

<!-- the following div should have a red border because
     if contains a div with class="a" -->
<div>
  <div class="a"></div>
</div>

<!-- the following div should have a blue border -->
<div>
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

**Note 2**: I know I can achieve this using javascript, but I just wondered whether this is possible using some unknown (to me) CSS features.

Comment: You might want to update the question to state, perhaps with blinking bold text, that you're trying to style the PARENT div, not its children. I know that info is in the question itself, but unless you want to get a ton of incorrect answers it's probably worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks @Seth. I tried to improve the question title and text. Please edit the question if you think it still unclear.

Comment: This is the perfect example of why this type of support in CSS would be ideal: `ol < li:nth-child(n+10) { margin-left: 2rem; } ol < li:nth-child(n+100) { margin-left: 3rem; } ol < li:nth-child(n+1000) { margin-left: 4rem; }` In an ideal world this would increase the margin of the `ol` dependent on the number of `li` children in contained so that the margin on the left would only be as wide as it needed to be.

Comment: Actually this feature is in progress with :has selector - https://bkardell.com/blog/canihas.html

Answer (score 183, accepted):

The syntax for that is:

```css
div:has(div.a) { border: solid 3px red; }
div:has(div.b) { border: solid 3px blue; }
```

---

<strike>As far as I'm aware, styling a parent element based on the child element is not an available feature of CSS. You'll likely need scripting for this.</strike>

It'd be wonderful if you could do something like `div[div.a]` or `div:containing[div.a]` as you said, but this isn't possible.

You may want to consider looking at [jQuery](http://jquery.com). Its selectors work very well with 'containing' types. You can select the div, based on its child contents and then apply a CSS class to the parent all in one line.

If you use jQuery, something along the lines of this would may work (untested but the theory is there):

```
$('div:has(div.a)').css('border', '1px solid red');
```

or

```
$('div:has(div.a)').addClass('redBorder');
```

combined with a CSS class:

```
.redBorder
{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Here's the documentation for the [jQuery "has" selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/).

Comment: Side note: for better performance, jQuery doc page for `:has` selector advises to use `.has()` method (http://api.jquery.com/has/) => applied to current question it would give for example `$('div').has('div.a').css('border', '1px solid red');`

Comment: For this to work one would have to use mutation observer, to check wether the child changed it's state...

Comment: This doesn't truly answer the question which is "Is there a way to do this with CSS".  It clearly states: "I know I can achieve this using javascript, but I just wondered whether this is possible using some unknown (to me) CSS features."

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has, I think this `:has` selector can work but it's in draft version and no browser supports it.

Comment: As of October 2022, it's supported in Chrome and Edge, but not Firefox unless the user messes with `about:config`

Answer (score 82):

Basically, no. The following *would* be what you were after in theory:

```
div.a < div { border: solid 3px red; }
```

Unfortunately it doesn't exist.

There are a few write-ups along the lines of "why the hell not". A well fleshed out one by Shaun Inman is pretty good:

http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2008/05/05/css_qualified_selectors

Update. Many years later, :has has arrived, browser support is increasing.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

12 years is a long time.

Comment: just an update 8 years later:  there is still no support for this selector method.

Comment: There is a working draft for this feature in the form of a [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo-class, but we'll only get to use it in CSS4. As of now (late 2019), JS is still the only way to achieve this functionality.

Comment: I believe this won't enable css styles, it will still need javascript to use the selector. Unless this has changed?

Comment: 9 years and do they think this feature is needless?

Comment: 11 years and still I and so many others are looking for a solution!

Comment: 12 years now and a quick note: there will be never a CSS4. https://css-tricks.com/css4/

Comment: ^ Not even a year later, and while there may never be a CSS4, [CSS using `:has()` is now supported in every major desktop browser](https://caniuse.com/css-has) to some degree (Gecko still has some feature gaps and requires an experimental preference setting to enable it), and on mobile devices in the Safari, Chrome, Android-builtin, and Opera browsers.

Answer (score 1):

On top of @kp's answer:

I'm dealing with this and in my case, I have to show a child element and correct the height of the parent object accordingly (auto-sizing is not working in a bootstrap header for some reason I don't have time to debug).

But instead of using javascript to modify the parent, I think I'll dynamically add a CSS class to the parent and CSS-selectively show the children accordingly. This will maintain the *decisions* in the logic and not based on a CSS state.

**tl;dr;** apply the `a` and `b` styles to the parent `<div>`, not the child (of course, not everyone will be able to do this. i.e. Angular components making decisions of their own).

```
<style>
  .parent            { height: 50px; }
  .parent div        { display: none; }
  .with-children     { height: 100px; }
  .with-children div { display: block; }
</style>

<div class="parent">
  <div>child</div>
</div>

<script>
  // to show the children
  $('.parent').addClass('with-children');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to change the cell padding of an element that contained an input checkbox for a table that's being dynamically rendered with DataTables:

```
<td class="dt-center">
    <input class="a" name="constCheck" type="checkbox" checked="">
</td>
```

After implementing the following line code within the [initComplete](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) function I was able to produce the correct padding, which fixed the rows from being displayed with an abnormally large height

```
 $('tbody td:has(input.a)').css('padding', '0px');
```

Now, you can see that the correct styles are being applied to the parent element:

```
<td class=" dt-center" style="padding: 0px;">
    <input class="a" name="constCheck" type="checkbox" checked="">
</td>
```

Essentially, this answer is an extension of @KP's answer, but the more collaboration of implementing this the better. In summation, I hope this helps someone else because it works! Lastly, thank you so much @KP for leading me in the right direction!