# Pure CSS3 solution to stripe table with multiple <tbody> elements?

Tags: html, css

I've got a table with multiple `<tbody>` elements. At a given time, only one `<tbody>` is displayed, or all of them are displayed.

I currently use this CSS3 code to stripe the table:

```css
table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #efefef;
}
```

When a single `<tbody>` element is shown, everything is (obviously) fine, but when multiple `<tbody>` elements are shown the CSS rules apply to each one separately, and each `<tbody>` has its own “stripes system”. Together the stripes may or may not look consistent, depending on the number of rows.

```
<tbody>
  <tr> [ODD]
  <tr> [EVEN]
  <tr> [ODD]
</tbody>
<tbody>
  <tr> [ODD]
  <tr> [EVEN]
</tbody>
…
```

Would I absolutely have to use JavaScript (… jQuery) to fix this? Or is there a pure CSS solution?

Comment: I can't see how to avoid jQuery unless you're able to keep your tables to have one tbody only.

Comment: Give each row a class 'ODD' or 'EVEN'.  Then use CSS to color the classes, not the table cells.

Comment: Related: [Select nth-child across multiple parents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652543/select-nth-child-across-multiple-parents)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*If* you're using jQuery then use the [`:even`](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) selector, (edited: to handle visibility) [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/FmLKq/1/):

```
$("table tr:visible:even").addClass("even");​
```

And a class like this:

```
.even { background: #efefef; }
```

Again, that's **if** you're using jQuery already, if you're not go with a pure javascript solution (including any library for *just* this is overkill) like [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince) posted.  Either way I don't see a pure CSS solution here...it's definitely a valid case, but not something that comes up often enough to make it spec-worthy.

Comment: That doesn't solve the question he's trying to have answered. This is just a jQuery version of his problem.

Comment: @Scott - It does solve the problem, did you look at the demo?  You have to remove and re-apply the class when visibility changes, just like the javascript solution...if you have a simpler non-javascript solution I'd love to see it, but I don't see how that's possible.

Comment: Ah this is correct, I completely misunderstood. I'm trying to change my vote but it's not allowing me unless an edit is made.

Comment: @Scott - Updated - added additional handling or visibility as per the question.

Comment: Ah nice, I wouldn't have considered visibility.

Comment: Well, I suppose I don't have a choice. :)
Thank you.

Comment: Question is tbody show/hide. When i removed style from tr and added display none in second tbody. "Like this" demo not worked well.

Comment: @shyamji1983 there are multiple ways to hide a tbody.  Also it *does* work fine, you're just trying a demo with an ancient version of jQuery.  Notice it works fine with the current version: http://jsfiddle.net/FmLKq/5/

Comment: You can actually use CSS to color the class.  I did this in my HTML5/CSS class.  We did not use any other languages.

Comment: I agree on `no pure css solution` part and upvote this simple yet nice answer

Answer (score 7):

If you have rows that are all the same height, you can cheat with a gradient, e.g.:

```css
#table {
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(pink 0, pink 1.6em, yellow 1.6em, yellow 3.2em);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    /* To account for headers; adjust size to account for footers.
     * You can also use a second (or third) gradient for both.
     */
    background-position: 0 1.4em;
}
```

If you can guarantee that all `<tbody>` elements have an even number of rows, you can also make use of that (even if the last one is hidden), but otherwise, you’re out of luck. Selectors Level 4 might have something to say about it, though, with something along the lines of

```css
#table > !tbody > tr:last-child:nth-child(even)
```

making up for the class.

[*Demo!*](http://dabblet.com/gist/8449588)

Comment: That selector matches `tbody` with an even number of children - I'm not sure that selector alone would be enough. I'm thinking of something like `tr:nth-match(even of #table > tbody > tr)` instead, which is probably equivalent to `$('#table > tbody > tr:odd')`, but Selectors 4 might not allow `!` or combinators in `:nth-match()` to be used in CSS, which would mean you'd still have to fall back to JS either way.

Comment: (I’m trying to think of ways to abuse wrapping and Roman-numeral-style CSS counters to have a *CSS2-compatible thing* for this, but no luck so far.)

Comment: @minitech The problem is turning the counter into a number that can use the modular operator http://codepen.io/Zeaklous/pen/djtBz

Comment: @BoltClock `nth-match` will not work, I examined that. See my answer.

Comment: Clever and upvoted, but giving the bounty to the "not possible" answer.

Answer (score 7):

After intensive research, I can state that

#### There is no pure CSS3 (not even CSS4) solution to match even/odd rows accross multiple parents.

All solutions you would think of are impossible:

1. Use the [`:nth-child` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo).

   **Verdict:** This will only work within a single parent.
2. Somehow involve the `tbody` tags with odd number of rows (color switchers) by counting their children and distinguishing those with odd rows in a similar way `nth-child(odd)` works.

   **Verdict:** In CSS it is not possible to count children, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8720931/684229). Beware of the confusing accepted answer - this is in fact counting siblings, not children
3. Try to match only some `tbody`s based on some children CSS rule, and thus being able to identify `tbody`s with odd number of children.

   **Verdict:** In CSS it is not possible to match elements according to their children:

   - [Apply CSS styles to an element depending on its child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2326499/684229)
   - [Complex CSS selector for parent of active child](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45004/684229)
   - [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/684229)
   - [Select element based on child class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3662645/684229)
4. CSS4 introduces a new selector [`:nth-match`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#the-nth-match-pseudo), which sounds promising as it doesn't contain the word "child" in it. So you would wonder if this would work:

```
:nth-match(even of tr) { background-color: #ccc; }
:nth-match(odd of tr) { background-color: #fff; }
```

**Verdict:** It doesn't work. If you look at the description, you see it will do exactly the same thing you observe:

> The `:nth-match(An+B of <selector>)`pseudo-class notation represents an
>   element that has `An+B-1` **siblings** that match the given selector list
>   before it in the document tree.

The problematic is the word **siblings** which mean it will only count *within* each tbody tag, as the `:nth-child` selectors do.

### Conclusion

There is no pure CSS (neither CSS3 nor CSS4) solution. You will have to refrain to either:

- javascript, e.g. the great jQuery solution mentioned by Nick Craver;
- minitech's background trick, but its use is limited to equal-height rows;
- changes in the HTML generation code.

Answer (score 1):

**If Use JQuery then Use this Code :**

```
//style for even CSS Class
<style>.even { background: #efefef; } </style>
```

**Add class to every second row of tables for styling purposes**

```
 <script>
   $('tbody').parents('.table-container').find('tr:even').addClass( 'even' );
 </script>
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="table-container">
    <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr> [ODD]
          <tr> [EVEN]
          <tr> [ODD]
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
          <tr> [ODD]
          <tr> [EVEN]
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution that for now won't work in any browser (as far as I know) would be using counters (on the tr) and then use that from w3c counter styles level 3:

### [w3c doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-css-counter-styles-3-20130221/)

> 3.1.1. Cycling Symbols: the ‘cyclic’ system
>
> The ‘cyclic’ counter system cycles repeatedly through its provided
> symbols, looping back to the beginning when it reaches the end of the
> list. It can be used for simple bullets (just provide a single counter
> symbol), or for cycling through multiple symbols. The first counter
> symbol is used as the representation of the value 1, the second
> counter symbol (if it exists) is used as the representation of the
> value 2, etc.
>
> If the system is ‘cyclic’, the ‘symbols’ descriptor must contain at
> least one counter symbol, or else the ‘@counter-style’ rule is
> invalid. This system is defined over all counter values.
>
> A "triangle bullet" counter style can be defined as:
>
> @counter-style triangle {     system: cyclic;     symbols: ‣;     suffix: ''; }
>
> It will then produce lists that look like:
>
> ‣  One ‣  Two ‣  Three         If there are N counter symbols and a
> representation is being constructed for the integer value, the
> representation is the counter symbol at index ( (value-1) mod N) of
> the list of counter symbols (0-indexed).

If I set this rule with 2 symbols, one a filled square an the other an empty square, I get a pseudo element that is alternating between a color and transparency.

Then I can force this pseudo element to extend to all the tr.

Comment: *“Then I can force this pseudo element to extend to all the tr.”* How?

Comment: I suppose `transform: scale(something big);` and `overflow: hidden;` would probably do the trick…

Comment: Providing a simple example code how this would work for the table would make this answer much more useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I think you would need script, as there is no `nth-grandchild` selector that would work relative to the `<table>`. You'd need script to make it work in older browsers anyway, so probably not a big deal.

```
var table= document.getElementById('sometable');
for (var i= table.rows.length; i-->0;)
    table.rows[i].className= i%2===0? 'stripe-even' : 'stripe-odd';
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I don't care about compatibility. I'm only going to support browsers that support CSS3. Writing a script, especially using jQuery, is not much of a problem. But I really wanted to avoid it, as the table is dynamic and I would have to reapply a lot.