# Select element based on child class

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way in CSS to select an element which has a sub-element with given class?

I want to apply a style to a `<ul>` list that has `<li>` with a particular class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS parent selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/css-parent-selector)

Comment: yes, it is a duplicate indeed. thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This isn't possible with css, since you're working against the cascade by selecting an ancestor based on a descendant.

The best I can offer and suggest is a jQuery approach:

```
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('.givenClassName').parent().addClass('something');
  }
);
```

This finds the element with the `givenClassName` and then selects its parent element and adds the class `something` to that element.

[@Blaenk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662645/css-selector-question/3662690#3662690) suggests an alternate approach, which is more versatile (his approach doesn't require the ancestor element to be the parent of the element you're selecting by).

Obviously other JS libraries, and JS all by itself, can achieve the same effect, though I can't offer particular advice, since I'm still only just familiarising myself with JS and mostly with jQuery (why yes, I *am* ashamed of myself...).

Comment: @Jeff Rupert, thanks for the +1 and correction (edited to correct) =)

Comment: Haha, I'm on the same boat as you regarding Javascript and jQuery. Been reading some books to get up to speed though. Javascript: The Good Parts and jQuery in Action, Second Edition

Comment: *jQuery: Novice to Ninja* (from O'Reilly) is pretty good. Though I've yet to come across the `.shuriken(200)` method... =)

Comment: My previous comment is wrong, the book's by Sitepoint (not O'Reilly).

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, this is unfortunately not possible with CSS.

If you can use Javascript though, jQuery has a nice way of doing this using the `closest()` method. The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) for it even lists an example very similar to yours: selecting a ul that has an li of a particular class.

```
$("li.some-class").closest("ul");
```

Forgive me if this is not the best way to do it in jQuery. I'm actually new to jQuery and this is one of the methods I've learned so far, and it seemed fitting.

Answer (score 2):

No. The CSS Cascade does not allow for this kind of selector.

The best solution in this case would be either to modify the DOM with JavaScript or to change up the resultant HTML to add classes to the `ul` tags.

Answer (score -6):

```
ul li {
    /* styles */
}
```

Is this what you're asking for?