# Not select Child class element (Jsoup)

Tags: html, dom, css-selectors, jsoup

Is there a way in **jsoup** to select all `<p>` tag elements except the one that contains `<iframe>` tag:

```
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p><iframe scr='..'></iframe></p>
...
<p>Text</p>
```

I have tried `document.select("p:not(iframe)")`

and

```
document.select("p:not(p iframe)")
```

but with no success, from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3662667/4509214) it says that working against the cascade by selecting an ancestor based on a descendant is **impossible** in **CSS**, but I saw some **jquery** solutions, so I'm wondering if there is solutions in jsoup to solve this problem

**EDIT:**

I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17027065/4509214), but it needs some additional java coding, I'm looking for a solution with only css selector that will come from a database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this -  `p:not(:has(iframe))`.
You can see a working example [here](http://try.jsoup.org/~llGBwh35ZOxtxd8E2iqHr8mfb6Y).

Comment: Perfect mate! Thanks, So helpful ;)