# How to select the first element of n>4 elements with CSS only?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm playing around with `nth-child` selector.

Say I have grid with rows of 4 elements each and my first and last element have classes of `ui-first-child` and `ui-last-child` respectively:

```
<ul>
 <li.ui-first-child>
 <li>
 <li>
 <li.ui-last-child>
</ul>
```

What I would like to do is select **the first element ONLY if there are more than 4 elements** using pure CSS.

So if there are five elements like this:

```
 <el.first><el><el><el>
 <el.last>
```

I want to override bottom-corners on the first element.

**Question:**
Is it possible with pure CSS/nth-child/first/last class to select the first element on a group of elements with number of elements > 4?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720931/can-css-detect-the-number-of-children-an-element-has

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I waited for half an hour so that maybe someone would find the answer, but this is the only thing I came up with, and it's problem is that it doesn't work for a "> n", but it works for a "= n". i.e it works only for a specific number, so it's half way what you asked for

```
li:first-child:nth-last-child(4) {
    /* Whatever here */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g3PDw/

EDIT:
Dude I nailed it. This one works perfectly
http://jsfiddle.net/g3PDw/9/

```
li:first-child:nth-last-child(n+5)
```

Comment: You need to tweak your selector to `(n+5)` as `(n+4)` [fails at four elements](http://jsfiddle.net/g3PDw/7/), for the OP only wanted to select if [more than four](http://jsfiddle.net/g3PDw/8/). But your answer was on the right track.