# fill the div with divs in a row (css)

Tags: css, css-float

I have div container with fix size 600px.
I want to fill with some number of divs **(number is dynamic value)** in one row.

Something like this:

```
|---------------------------container-------------------------|
|----box1----||----box2-----||-----box3-----||------box4------|
```

All boxes must have same size

Comment: What scripting language are you using?

Comment: Do you know, before you try to render, how many DIVs you have in the container?

Comment: Yes, I know how many DIVs have before render.

Answer (score 6):

**Table-layout based answer (pure CSS)** : *http://jsfiddle.net/QheN7/1/*

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="child">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="child">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="child">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="child">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="child">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="child">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<button>Add div</button>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    display:table;
    border:1px solid #000;
    width:600px;
    height:20px;
}

.child{
    display:table-cell;
    height:20px;
}

.child:nth-child(odd){
    background-color:#aaa;
}

.child:nth-child(even){
    background-color:#666;
}
```

I have used JS only for adding more divs, otherwise it is not needed:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    var newChild = $('.container').find('.child').first();
    newChild.clone().appendTo($('.container'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want..You'll need javascript though (I know you didn't tag it here): **http://jsfiddle.net/QheN7/**

Screen capture:

[image]

CSS:

```
.container{
    overflow:auto;
    border:1px solid #000;
    width:600px;
}

.child{
    float:left;
    height:20px;
}

.child:nth-child(odd){
    background-color:#aaa;
}

.child:nth-child(even){
    background-color:#666;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<button>Add div</button>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    function setWidth(){
        var container = $('.container'),
            children = $('.child'),
            containerWidth = container.width(),
            noOfChildren = children.length;
        children.width(containerWidth/noOfChildren);
    }
    $('button').on('click', function(){
        var newChild = $('.container').find('.child').first();
        newChild.clone().appendTo($('.container'));
        setWidth();
    });
    setWidth();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible to solve the problem with pure CSS, but it doesn't work in all the browsers. Your questions is kinda duplication of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720931/can-css-detect-the-number-of-children-an-element-has) one. The idea is to set the width of the divs based on their number.

```
/* one item */
li:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(1) {
    width: 100%;
}

/* two items */
li:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(2),
li:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(1) {
    width: 50%;
}

/* three items */
li:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(3),
li:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(2),
li:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(1) {
    width: 33.3333%;
}
```