# How to make multiple divs always fill out the whole browser size?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to have a `div` which should fill the whole screen width and height. Inside that `div` I want to add several other `div` not knowing however how many exactly (could be 3 but could also be 40). Is it possible using only CSS techniques to make these `divs` fill out the whole width and height of the surrounding `div`? So when there are only four `divs` they would need to be much larger than if there were 40 `divs`. I tried achieving this effect using Flexbox, but I didn´t succeeded.

Comment: Why not use `width:100%; height: 100%; position: relative;` for each one?

Comment: Using percentages will help.

Comment: can you use javascript/jQuery?

Comment: Wondering why anyone would downvote my question, is it so difficult to understand? As I mentioned I only want pure CSS techniques without JavaScript. I cant use fixed percentages as I dont know the amount of `divs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I found for my question: [Filling space with Flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/filling-space-last-row-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [Demo](http://jsbin.com/wumukepa/1/edit)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="inner">1</div>
    <div class="inner">2</div>
    <div class="inner">3</div>
    <div class="inner">4</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrap {
position:absolute;
border:1px solid black;
height:100%;
width:100%;
display:flex;
flex-flow:row wrap;
justify-content:space-around;
}

.inner {
position:realtive;
border:1px solid red;
background-color:silver;
height:100%;
width:20%;
}
```

The tricky part here is setting the width of `.inner` elements.
Since it is in percentage, so what you should do is divide 100 by number of `.inner` elements. 
Here there are 4 `.inner` elements so 100%/4 = 25%.This 25% will be your width of `.inner` elements.
But I have set the width to 20%,why? Because of the `justify-content:space-around;` and `flex-flow:row wrap;` properties of `#wrap` element.
If I set the width of `.inner` elements to 25%, one element will wrap to the bottom.
You should be able to detect the nearest value, in which the `.inner` elements donot wrap to the bottom, by yourself.In this case the nearest value of width was 20%.

Comment: Thank you but this won´t work if the number of .inner elements is not fixed but can vary, am I wrong?

Comment: You can add as many no. of .inner elements as you want.But if you increase or decrease the no. of .inner elements then you will have to change the width of .inner elements.And I have explained the procedure of changing the width of .inner elements in the last section of my answer.

Comment: @UmairKhan, I think the OP is trying to build the page to handle a dynamic number of `.inner` elements

Answer (score 0):

Try this ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/btg63ezy/) that appends a random # of DIVs to the BODY then sizes them as a percentage):

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body { 
  position: relative; 
  margin: 0; 
  paddding: 0; 
}
div { 
  width: 100%; 
  position: relative; 
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('div').css("height",(100/$('div').length) + "%");
// this sets the heights to equal percentages
```

Comment: Thank you but I am looking for a pure CSS solution.

Comment: I added an alternative, pure CSS solution as a different answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pure CSS3 Solution: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/btg63ezy/3/)

(this involves using a lot of individual style rules - 40 if your maximum number of DIVs is 40)

```
html, body { height: 100%; min-height: 100%; }
body { position: relative; margin: 0; paddding: 0; }
div.inner { width: 100%; position: relative; }
// this is where the CSS3 magic happens - these selectors can catch for an individual 
// case in regards to the count of items on the page
/* one item */
div.inner:first-child:nth-last-child(1) { height: 100%; }
/* two items */
div.inner:first-child:nth-last-child(2), div.inner:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ div.inner { height: 50%; }
/* three items */
div.inner:first-child:nth-last-child(3), div.inner:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ div.inner { height: 33.3333%; }
//...and so on up until your desired maximum of items...
```

[*Reference*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12198561/643482)

*Supported in IE9+*