# Setting different margin to the li first child based on the number of list elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, siblings

I'm trying to set a different CSS margin value to the first element of LI in UL depending on the number of LI elements.
i.e

```
<ul>
 <li> (margin: 20%)
 <li>
 <li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li> (margin: 40%)
 <li>
</ul>
```

Tried with `:nth-last-child(n + 3)` but it doesn't work.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Somehow I had forgotten about that duplicate question, despite having had quite a bit of involvement in it in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/etw2259o/3/)

> styles can be applied to the children nodes based on the number of
>   siblings they have.

html

```
<ul>
    <li>one item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>two items</li>
    <li>two items</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>three items</li>
    <li>three items</li>
    <li>three items</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>four items</li>
    <li>four items</li>
    <li>four items</li>
    <li>four items</li>
</ul>
```

css

```
 li:first-child:nth-last-child(1) {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

li:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ li {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

li:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ li {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

li:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ li {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

 li:first-child:nth-last-child(4) {
     margin-left:10px;
    color:red;
 }

 li:first-child:nth-last-child(3) {
     margin-left:20px;
    color:green;
 }

 li:first-child:nth-last-child(2) {
     margin-left:30px;
    color:blue;
 }

 li:first-child:nth-last-child(1) {
     margin-left:40px;
     color:gray;
 }
```

ref : [Can CSS detect the number of children an element has?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720931/can-css-detect-the-number-of-children-an-element-has)

Comment: This really should have been a duplicate vote instead.