# How to select all list elements based on their total number in CSS without JS or flexbox?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, children

Say I have a list with n items and I want to make the width of the first list item "rowspan=2". The width will change depending on the number of n, but in the example below:

```
<ul>
  <!-- <li>Row-2-1</li>-->
  <li class="ui-grid-span-2">SPAN 2</li>
  <li>Row 2-3</li>
  <li>Row 2-4</li>
  <li>Row 2-5</li>
  <li>Row 2-6</li>
</ul>
```

This would change this:

```
|-----------------------------------|
|  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |
|-----------------------------------|
```

to this:

```
|-----------------------------------|
|  1  |   SPAN2   |  4  |  5  |  6  |
|-----------------------------------|
```

my original six items are now reduced to five (four regular items, one item spanning two). So I'm writing my selector like this:

```
ul > li:nth-child(-n+5).ui-grid-span-2 {
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

but it does not work. Instead this rule applies:

```
ul > li:nth-child(-n+2).ui-grid-span-2 {
    width: 66.66%;
}
```

and I don't understand why.

**Question:**
How do I address "all childs of five childs, the one with class: ui-grid-span-2" directly. This means, instead of all cells being 1/6 width = 16.66%, the one with the class assigned should be 2/6 = 33.33%.

**EDIT...**:
This is not a dupe of [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720931/can-css-detect-the-number-of-children-an-element-has). The solution of Vera allows to set the width based on total number of cells either by siblings (does not apply here, because if the 3rd cell was a rowspan=2, I could only set the width of the following cells, not the previous ones). The original solution requires a line of code for every cell (if have n=10 max) and then doing this for every *-span class = a giant pile of CSS.

**ANSWER**:
Found out why. Selectors are "greedy" = "take first seven" will include/override "take first six". Solution below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can CSS detect the number of children an element has?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720931/can-css-detect-the-number-of-children-an-element-has)

Comment: @Vandervals: I know this answer. this does not help at all.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: The obvious answer is to use a modifier class on a list that has 5 items.  If the list is dynamic, then you would need to use some JS to count the items, and then add a class accordingly.  But what you are trying to do will never work as is, and is far too complicated to be practical.

Comment: Can you reiterate what you're trying to do? I also can't seem to understand your goal.

Comment: @Paulie_D: I have to stretch the cell with "span-2" to 2/6: 33.33% with the others remaining on 1/6: 16.66%

Comment: Frankly, this sounds like something an actual `table` would solve with `colspan`

Comment: How about an illustration of your desired result as opposed to a textual description?

Comment: @Paulie_D: yes. This is probably what I will be doing eventually. For now I did it the harder way (see below).

Answer (score 3):

Flexbox seems to be a solution here although the actual question seems unclear.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex
}
li {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.ui-grid-span-2 {
  flex-grow: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="ui-grid-span-2">SPAN 2</li>
  <li>Row 2-3</li>
  <li>Row 2-4</li>
  <li>Row 2-5</li>
  <li>Row 2-6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You should mention that in the question so that other users don't waste their time coming up with solutions you won't accept.

Comment: so my idea was to write a selector capturing all cells based on their total number including "rowspan-cell" and then applying a width to only the "rowspan-cell"

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16.6%;
    background-color: red;
}
li:last-child, li:first-child, li:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: brown;
}
.ui-grid-span-2 {
    width: 32.2%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="ui-grid-span-2">SPAN 2</li><li>
    Row 2-3</li><li>
    Row 2-4</li><li>
    Row 2-5</li><li>
    Row 2-6</li>
</ul>
```

I think you **CAN'T** do what you want for a dinamic number of `< li >`'s without JS or flex

Answer (score -1):

Ok, after some more meddling my original idea works. This means if you have the following HTML:

```
<ul class="grid-items">
  <!-- <li>Row 1-1</li> -->
  <li class="ui-grid-span-2">SPAN 2</li>
  <li>Row 1-3</li>
  <li>Row 1-4</li>
  <li>Row 1-5</li>
  <li>Row 1-6</li>
</ul>
```

the width of the list elements can be set as I intended:

```
ul > li:nth-child(-n+4).ui-grid-span-2 {
  width: 33.33%;
}
ul > li:nth-child(-n+3).ui-grid-span-3 {
  width: 50%;
}
ul > li:nth-child(-n+2).ui-grid-span-4 {
  width: 66.66%;
}
ul > li:nth-child(-n+1).ui-grid-span-5 {
  width: 83.33%;
}
```

Note that by spanning multiple cells, the total number of cells change, too, so the pseudo-selector must be adjusted depending on cells spanned. To make it work with multiple ranges of cells (not always 6 cells as above) it is also required to add a class on the list element to note the number of cells in a row. Otherwise larger selector (take first 8 items) will overwrite/encapsulate smaller ones (take first 7 items).

Still not happy with it and only supporting a single `rowspan` per row, but... it works and it's not using any of the above proposed solutions (~ siblings, x*y cells * n rowspans rules, flexbox or tables). Keep in mind, the regular cell width declarations need to be amended, too, as a row using `rowspan` will have less number of cells but require the original intended number of cells' width.

Final CSS for up to 8 cell grids (I have not combined declarations for sake of comprehensability).

**Note**:
- section ROWSPAN is the relevant section
 - before I ensure cell width is set based on intended not actual number of cells
- selectors are cutoff for relevance.

```
/* base width */
ul > li {
  width: auto;
}

/* "cell width" */
ul > li:first-child:nth-last-child(1) {
  width: 100%;
}
ul > li:first-child:nth-last-child(2),
ul > li:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ li {
  width: 50%;
}
ul.ui-grid-column-3 > li:first-child:nth-last-child(n),
ul.ui-grid-column-3 > li:first-child:nth-last-child(n) ~ li  {
  width: 33.3333%;
}
ul.ui-grid-column-4 > li:first-child:nth-last-child(n),
ul.ui-grid-column-4 > li:first-child:nth-last-child(n) ~ li {
  width: 25%;
}
ul.ui-grid-column-5 > li:first-child:nth-last-child(n),
ul.ui-grid-column-5 > li:first-child:nth-last-child(n) ~ li {
  width: 20%;
}
ul.ui-grid-column-6 > li:first-child:nth-last-child(n),
ul.ui-grid-column-6 > li:first-child:nth-last-child(n) ~ li {
  width: 16.667%;
}
ul.ui-grid-column-7 > li:first-child:nth-last-child(n),
ul.ui-grid-column-7 > li:first-child:nth-last-child(n) ~ li {
  width: 14.285714286%;
}
ul.ui-grid-column-8 > li:first-child:nth-last-child(n),
ul.ui-grid-column-8 > li:first-child:nth-last-child(n) ~ li {
  width: 12.5%;
}

/* ROWSPAN */
/* 3 cells */
ul.ui-grid-column-3 > li:nth-child(-n+2).ui-grid-span-2 {
  width: 66.666%;
}
/* 4 cells */
ul.ui-grid-column-4 > li:nth-child(-n+3).ui-grid-span-2 {
  width: 50%;
}
ul.ui-grid-column-4 > li:nth-child(-n+2).ui-grid-span-3 {
  width: 75%;
}
/* 5 cells */
ul.ui-grid-column-5 > li:nth-child(-n+4).ui-grid-span-2 {
  width: 40%;
}
ul.ui-grid-column-5 > li:nth-child(-n+3).ui-grid-span-3 {
  width: 60%;
}
ul.ui-grid-column-5 > li:nth-child(-n+2).ui-grid-span-4 {
  width: 80%;
}
/* 6 cells */
ul.ui-grid-column-6 > li:nth-child(-n+5).ui-grid-span-2 {
  width: 33.33%;
}
ul.ui-grid-column-6 > li:nth-child(-n+4).ui-grid-span-3 {
  width: 50%;
}
ul.ui-grid-column-6 > li:nth-child(-n+4).ui-grid-span-4 {
  width: 66.66%;
}
ul.ui-grid-column-6 > li:nth-child(-n+4).ui-grid-span-5 {
  width: 83.33%;
}
/* 7 cells */
ul.ui-grid-column-7 > li:nth-child(-n+6).ui-grid-span-2 {
  width: 28.571428571%;
}
ul.ui-grid-column-7 > li:nth-child(-n+5).ui-grid-span-3 {
  width: 42.857142857%;
}
ul.ui-grid-column-7 > li:nth-child(-n+4).ui-grid-span-4 {
  width: 57.142857142%;
}
ul.ui-grid-column-7 > li:nth-child(-n+3).ui-grid-span-5 {
  width: 71.428571428%;
}
ul.ui-grid-column-7 > li:nth-child(-n+2).ui-grid-span-6 {
  width: 85.714285714%;
}

/* 8 cells */
ul.ui-grid-column-8 > li:nth-child(-n+7).ui-grid-span-2 {
  width: 25%;
}
ul.ui-grid-column-8 > li:nth-child(-n+6).ui-grid-span-3 {
  width: 37.5%;
}
ul.ui-grid-column-8 > li:nth-child(-n+5).ui-grid-span-4 {
  width: 50%;
}
ul.ui-grid-column-8 > li:nth-child(-n+4).ui-grid-span-5 {
  width: 62.5%;
}
ul.ui-grid-column-8 > li:nth-child(-n+3).ui-grid-span-6 {
  width: 75%;
}
ul.ui-grid-column-8 > li:nth-child(-n+2).ui-grid-span-7 {
  width: 87.5%;
}

/* responsive */
@media (max-width: 32em) {
ul > li,
ul[class*="ui-grid-column"] > li {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```