# css based on number of children/siblings

Tags: css

Is it possible to write css using number of child/sibling elements?

for example

```
tr with 4 .container /* tr .container */
{
width:25%
}

tr with 3.container /*tr .container*/
{
width:33%
}
```

Comment: No...not that simply but you could have multiple [**Quantity Queries**](http://quantityqueries.com/)...but the CSS would be quite bloated. A Pre-processor like LESS or SASS could help but still generate a lot of CSS.

Comment: Try [nth-child()](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) css selector.

Comment: That said, there are some `display` layout options that can do this for you depending on your actual requirement.

Comment: `jquery` might be the option here..

Comment: well in the case of your example, flexbox would be good

Comment: This should help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720931/can-css-detect-the-number-of-children-an-element-has