# How to select only the siblings that are before the element in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, siblings

When I hover over a ring I would like the ring hovered and all the rings under it to be colored in as well. For example: If I hover over ring_two_fill_1 I would like ring_one_fill_1 to be filled in as well as ring_two_fill_1. I am making a progress graphic that displays the level you are at.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="615.7px"
 height="621px" viewBox="0 0 615.7 621" enable-background="new 0 0 615.7 621" xml:space="preserve">

    <g id="level_one">
        <path id="ring_three_fill_1" class="ring-fill"/>
        <path id="ring_two_fill_1" class="ring-fill"/>
        <path id="ring_one_fill_1" class="ring-fill"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: You write "before" in your title but elements you refer to in code sample is "after", so is it "before" or "after"? ... If "before" in code structure, you need script, otherwise css hover works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720931/can-css-detect-the-number-of-children-an-element-has

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea, you'll basically have to end up using next() method. Here's an example of such functionality for a simple list:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  ul li {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 2px 0;
    background-color: lightpink;
  }
  ul li.active {
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
```

jQuery:

```
var lis = $('li');
function hoverIn () {
    $(this).addClass("active");
    if($(this).next().length != 0) {
        hoverIn.call($(this).next(), null); 
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
function hoverOut () {
    lis.removeClass("active");
}
lis.on("mouseenter", hoverIn);
lis.on("mouseleave", hoverOut);
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I add the class to the path? Just adding a class is not doing anything.

Comment: Can't use addClass with SVG. Works now like this:
`$(this).attr("class", "ring-fill active");`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Jquery **[next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)** method and `hover` event :

```
$('body').on('hover', '.ring-fill', function(){
     $(this).css('color', 'GREEN');
     $(this).next('.ring-fill').css('color', 'GREEN');
});
```

**NOTE :** You miss double quote `"` after avery `class="ring-fill`.

Hope this helps.