# How to detect CSS flex wrap event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

I have flex container with items inside. How to detect flex wrap event? I want to apply some new css to elements that have been wrapped. I suppose that it is impossible to detect wrap event by pure css. But it would be very powerful feature! I can try to "catch" this break point event by media query when element wraps into new line/row. But this is a terrible approach. I can try to detect it by script, but it's also not very good.

[image: Look at the picture]

I am very surprised, but simple $("#element").resize() doesn't work to detect height or width changes of flex container to apply appropriate css to child elements. LOL.

I have found that only this example of jquery code works
[jquery event listen on position changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743144/jquery-event-listen-on-position-changed)

But still terribly.

Comment: you **can't** detect wrapping in CSS- whether you are using `flexbox` or `float`, you'd better off with `media queries`...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. May be there is a simple way to detect it by JS? I think there is no point to "catch" floating breaking/wrapping point for flex elements through media query.

Comment: What is causing the items to wrap - a screen resize? more elements being added?

Comment: Yes. Screen resize causing elements to wrap. I want to position elements appropriately, add some margin/padding to aling them and do some other stuff after each element has been wrapped. All in all if I would be able to detect flex wrapping it wuld be very useful! It is very strange that it is impossible to detect breaking point of flex wrapping.

Comment: What is causing the elements to wrap in the first place? Do they have a `min-width`, or the content prevents them from shrinking so they wrap?

Comment: Сontent prevents them from shrinking so they wrap. Simple question. We have three elements in row with different width. When we resize container last element wraps. How to align last element to the end of a row or align it to the second element?

Comment: This is biggest issue I always run into. Media queries sucks a lot, flex is nice for simple wrapping but many times you want to change alignment for wrapped elements :/ ano no real solution for this yet.

Comment: I feel you bro, welcome to css in 2k19. Flexbox definitely needs something like `:wrapped` pseudo selector to solve this problem.I think even css-grid won't solve this problem but mb will reduce media queries count in your css style.

Comment: For the case of adding margins, you could use a "spacer" element instead. It's ugly but it works. Flex wrapping is one feature that makes flex better than grid for some kinds of layouts.

Answer (score 31):

Here's one potential solution. There might be other gotchas and edge cases you need to check for.

The basic idea is to loop through the flex `items` and test their `top` position against the previous sibling. If the `top` value is greater (hence further down the page) then the item has wrapped.

The function `detectWrap` returns an array of DOM elements that have wrapped, and could be used to style as desired.

The function could ideally be used with a [`ResizeObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) (while using [`window`'s `resize` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) as a fallback) as a trigger to check for wrapping as the window is resized or as elements in the page change due to scripts and other user-interaction. Because the StackOverflow code window doesn't resize it won't work here.

Here's a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/brettdewoody/pen/rrKpPp) that works with a screen resize.

```js
var detectWrap = function(className) {
  
  var wrappedItems = [];
  var prevItem = {};
  var currItem = {};
  var items = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    currItem = items[i].getBoundingClientRect();
    if (prevItem && prevItem.top < currItem.top) {
      wrappedItems.push(items[i]);
    }
    prevItem = currItem;
  };
  
  return wrappedItems;

}

window.onload = function(event){
  var wrappedItems = detectWrap('item');
  for (var k = 0; k < wrappedItems.length; k++) {
    wrappedItems[k].className = "wrapped";
  }
};
```

```css
div  {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div > div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #222222;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Arial;
  min-width: 300px;
}

div.wrapped {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">B</div>
  <div class="item">C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I think this snippet will be very useful for everyone. All in all I think that flexbox needs new css property such as "wrapped" or something like this to get rid of js spaghetti. Also this snippet could be improved. For example to detect all wrapped element instantly when page is loaded and haven't been resized yet. And it is rewrites previous css style of each element now.

Comment: How would you handle the following scenario - let's say you have 3 items. The first item goes full-width. So the 2nd and 3rd items are on the 2nd row. Would the 3rd item be considered wrapped?

Comment: Nice question. 3-rd element wouldn'tbe considered as wrapped relatively to 2-nd item. The best way in this case is to check whether the parent element of the class with "display: flex" css property. Then you can check each child item that has ben wrapped. I need to improve snippet.

Answer (score 9):

Little bit improved snippet on jQuery for this purpose.

```
wrapped();

$(window).resize(function() {
   wrapped();
});

function wrapped() {
    var offset_top_prev;

    $('.flex-item').each(function() {
       var offset_top = $(this).offset().top;

      if (offset_top > offset_top_prev) {
         $(this).addClass('wrapped');
      } else if (offset_top == offset_top_prev) {
         $(this).removeClass('wrapped');
      }

      offset_top_prev = offset_top;
   });
}
```

Comment: If the flex-direction is column, then change the if statements to:
if (offset_top < offset_top_prev) {} else {}. Also, if using bootstrap 4/5, then the selector should be $('.d-flex > *') to select all flex items.

Answer (score 6):

I've modified **sansSpoon**'s code to work even if the element isn't at the absolute top of the page. Codepen: https://codepen.io/tropix126/pen/poEwpVd

```js
function detectWrap(node) {
    for (const container of node) {
        for (const child of container.children) {
            if (child.offsetTop > container.offsetTop) {
                child.classList.add("wrapped");
            } else {
                child.classList.remove("wrapped");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `margin-top` shouldn't be applied to items since it's factored into `getBoundingClientRect` and will trigger the wrapped class to apply on all items.

Comment: We should be using `for(of)` instead of `Array.prototype.forEach` btw. Using `.forEach` introduces closures and has worse performance. Also, reading _and writing_ to the DOM in a single loop is really bad for UX because the browser needs to perform layout operations between each loop iteration. Instead have two separate loops: the first gathers size information for all relevant elements, the second loop then modifies the DOM (like toggling the `wrapped` class) without reading any properties that would trigger a relayout.

Comment: Yes, I wrote this a while ago when I was unaware of the downsides of `Array.prototype.forEach()`. Should probably rewrite my solution.

Comment: Another thing worth noting is that if the parent container has a position: relative (or absolute), then the offsetTop of the direct child will be 0 if it aligns to the top of its parent. Can just set position:relative and check child offsetTop against 0.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634770/get-position-offset-of-element-relative-to-a-parent-container

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a similar approach in determining if a `<li>` has been wrapped in an `<ul>` that has it's display set to `flex`.

```
ul = document.querySelectorAll('.list');

function wrapped(ul) {

    // loops over all found lists on the page - HTML Collection
    for (var i=0; i<ul.length; i++) {

        //Children gets all the list items as another HTML Collection
        li = ul[i].children;

        for (var j=0; j<li.length; j++) {
            // offsetTop will get the vertical distance of the li from the ul.
            // if > 0 it has been wrapped.
            loc = li[j].offsetTop;
            if (loc > 0) {
                li[j].className = 'wrapped';
            } else {
                li[j].className = 'unwrapped';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed elements will typically wrap in relation to the first element. Comparing offset top of each element to the first element is a simpler approach. This works for wrap and wrap-reverse. (Probably won't work if elements use flex order)

```js
var wrappers = $('.flex[class*="flex-wrap"]'); //select flex wrap and wrap-reverse elements

    if (wrappers.length) { //don't add listener if no flex elements
        $(window)
            .on('resize', function() {
                wrappers.each(function() {
                    var prnt = $(this),
                        chldrn = prnt.children(':not(:first-child)'), //select flex items
                        frst = prnt.children().first();

                    chldrn.each(function(i, e) { $(e).toggleClass('flex-wrapped', $(e).offset().top != frst.offset().top); }); //element has wrapped
                    prnt.toggleClass('flex-wrapping', !!prnt.find('.flex-wrapped').length); //wrapping has started
                    frst.toggleClass('flex-wrapped', !!!chldrn.filter(':not(.flex-wrapped)').length); //all are wrapped
               });
            })
            .trigger('resize'); //lazy way to initially call the above
    }
```

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
}

.flex.flex-wrap {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex.flex-wrap-reverse {
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}

.flex.flex-1 > * { /*make items equal width*/
    flex: 1;
}

.flex > * {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.cc-min-width-200 > * { /*child combinator*/
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="flex flex-1 flex-wrap-reverse cc-min-width-200">
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>There</div>
    <div>World</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using media queries for this type of task, it's too unstable.
Think of the work involved when another flex item is added, or the text length changes, and you have to rejig those media queries.

Instead consider using the Resize Observer API.

A list of links in a flex box:

```
<ul class=flex_box role=list>
    <li><a href="#/">Fake link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/">Fake link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/">Fake link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/">Fake link 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/">Fake link 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.flex_box {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0;
    gap: 1rem;
}

/* Optional coloring prettiness */
.flex_box > * {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
.flex_box-wrapped > .flex_item-wrapped {
    background-color: #333
}
```

Upon wrapping, the script adds class `flex_box-wrapped` to the flex container, and `flex_item-wrapped` to each flex item which has wrapped.

This is achieved by testing the top position of each item against the first item.

When the browser width (or height, or font-size) changes the Resize Observer API recalculates and amends each class name accordingly.

```
// An IFEE here, but you can roll your own:
const flexBoxWrapDetection = (_ => {
  'use strict';

  const flexBoxQuery = '.flex_box';
  const boxWrappedClass = 'flex_box-wrapped';
  const itemWrappedClass = 'flex_item-wrapped';


  // Rounded for inline-flex sub-pixel discrepencies:
  const getTop = item => Math.round(item.getBoundingClientRect().top);


  const markFlexboxAndItemsWrapState = flexBox => {

    // Acts as a throttle, 
    // Prevents hitting ResizeObserver loop limit,
    // Optimal timing for visual change:
    requestAnimationFrame(_ => {

      const flexItems = flexBox.children;

      // Needs to be in a row for the calculations to work
      flexBox.setAttribute('style', 'flex-direction: row');

      const firstItemTop = getTop(flexItems[0]);
      const lastItemTop = getTop(flexItems[flexItems.length - 1]);

      // Add / remove wrapped class to each wrapped item
      for (const flexItem of flexItems) {
        if (firstItemTop < getTop(flexItem)) {
          flexItem.classList.add(itemWrappedClass);
        } else {
          flexItem.classList.remove(itemWrappedClass);
        }
      }

      // Remove flex-direction:row used for calculations
      flexBox.removeAttribute('style');

      // Add / remove wrapped class to the flex container
      if (firstItemTop >= lastItemTop) {
        flexBox.classList.remove(boxWrappedClass);
      } else {
        flexBox.classList.add(boxWrappedClass);
      }
    });
  };


  // Each flex box with the class .flex_box:
  const flexBoxes = document.querySelectorAll(flexBoxQuery);
  for (const flexBox of flexBoxes) {

    markFlexboxAndItemsWrapState(flexBox);

    // Listen for dimension changes on the flexbox
    // EDIT: If there's a lot of flexboxes, it would probably be better to use an event handler rather than adding to each individualually,
    new ResizeObserver(entries =>
      entries.forEach(entry => markFlexboxAndItemsWrapState(entry.target))
    ).observe(flexBox);

  }
})();
```

There's a demo CodePen: [Flex-wrap detection script](https://codepen.io/2kool2/pen/eYPNaWX?editors=0100) which also shows how to switch between horizontal and vertical as soon as the flex box wraps or unwraps.

The demo also works with `direction: rtl;` and / or `flex-wrap: row-reverse;`.

Comment: Thank you, it's nice to have one more example here. Seems there is a little bug in your CodePen demo with the second list: when the parent box is resized then every list item is wrapped but not all of them are assigned the new `.flex_item-wrapped` class. So, all items are wrapped but only a few of them have the wrapped class.

Comment: @mr.boris Thanks for raising the issue. It doesn't affect the example above but I've amended the CodePen version to add `.flex_item-wrapped` class to every item on the "switched" example.

Comment: Having attribute/class changes and getBoundingClientRect mixed like in this code will force many reflows and will be bad for performance.

Comment: @HolgerJeromin - Not really a performance issue. It only fires upon a width change, and even then it waits for a spare cycle. It may become problematic if you were to constantly spin your phone. 
Though personally, if I were controlling many flexboxes on the same page I'd be more likely to use an event handler.

Comment: You have no idea when this code is running. I have some 100 grids (with lets say 10 children) in my DOM with my very dynamic application. A forced reflow costs here 25ms according to devTools. Checking all 1000 `getBoundingClientRect` after a class change sums up to 25 seconds. Good for your use case this is "not really a performance issue".

Comment: @HolgerJeromin - I'm reasonably certain this method is the most performant solution offered in this thread, especially when given an unexpected extreme which no one here has specifically designed for.
An example of this method with 500 flexboxes each with 10 children: https://codepen.io/2kool2/pen/dyarpVN?editors=0010
But it does become less responsive at 1000, and admittedly does not have a 25ms render per flex item. What do you suggest as an improvement?

Comment: More performant would be: One loop to fetch all getBoundingClientRect. And a second loop which manipulates all classes.

Comment: The codepen.io example from 2kool2 had task duration of 70-140ms for the calculation with a wall of forced reflow warnings. https://codepen.io/HolgerJeromin/pen/OJdYgdy?editors=0010 needs less than 5 ms for the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants to find the last element of the row from where wrapped elements started can use the below logic. It's applicable for multiple lines as well

```
       window.onresize = function (event) {
            const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.borrower-detail');
            let previousElement = {};
            let rowTop = elements[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;
            elements.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('last-el-of-row'))
            elements.forEach(el => {
                const elementTop = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;

                if (rowTop < elementTop) {
                    previousElement.classList.add('last-el-of-row');
                    rowTop = elementTop;
                }

                previousElement = el;
            })
        };
```