# How to know the number of child elements

Tags: css

I have to calculate the width depending on the number of elements inside my parent element. 
To be more explicit: let's say that I need to know the number of `li`'s inside a `ul` element.
Here is my pseudo code:

```
width:percentage((floor(100/numberOfLi))-1)/100;
```

Unfortunately `:nth-child`, does not provide what I need.

Is there a way to achieve that, if not I will set it using jquery...

Comment: It's not possible to get the No of child's in CSS.

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720931/can-css-detect-the-number-of-children-an-element-has

Comment: ok, many thanks for the info. I will compute it using JQuery then.

Comment: No need to use jQuery when you could just do document.getElementById('').children.length with plain javascript.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qxcco4jt/1/ check this its may help ful                                        alert( "Size: " + $("li").size() );

Comment: true I could do it without JQuery, but as I already use it in that project, it does not matter. solution $myTag.length; works fine, size() is deprecated