# CSS child's element selector - HTML Email

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am trying to find a way to change the css for a class, only if it's inside a table with 4 td's.
The code will probably explain better what is my problem.

HTML

```
<table class="myclass">
<tr>
  <td>1 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
  <td>2 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
  <td>3 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table class="myclass">
<tr>
  <td>1 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
  <td>2 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
  <td>3 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
  <td>4 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.myclass td:first-child:nth-last-child(3),td:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ td {
        background-color:white !important;
    }
.myclass td:first-child:nth-last-child(4),td:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ td {
        background-color:red !important;
    }
.myclass2 {
  color:blue;
}
```

a JSFiddle is ready: [JSFIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/fhyd9cp7/)

What I am trying to do is changing the style of "myclass2" only for the elements included in the table with 4 TDs, not with the table with 3 TDs.
Is that possible at all?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible since the only way to ascertain there are four cells in the `<table>` is with the fourth, or last, `<td>`; and there is (as yet) no way to select the previous siblings of that fourth `<td>`. This is, to the best of my knowledge, a problem that will require JavaScript in some way.

Comment: @Vohuman this is wrong.  see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720931/can-css-detect-the-number-of-children-an-element-has . Also my example prove that it's somehow possible.

Comment: @DavidThomas thanks. I am developing an HTML Email so I won't be able to use js :-)

Comment: Hi MeV, so if the table has 4 TDs it should have class myclass2 whereas the others should not have this class?

Comment: @IPAddress correct. But I would like to make this only via CSS, not via HTML, as the HTML will be dynamic

Comment: @MeV: interesting find! So surely `td:nth-last-child(4), td:nth-last-child(4) ~ td {/* css */}` should style the `<td>` elements according to your needs? Although there is a risk that a `<table>` with five, or more, `<td>` element siblings will cause problems with those styles: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/o4on86zs/).

Comment: @DavidThomas yes, you are right, with more than 5 elements it could be a problem. See below for the right answer :-)

Comment: I didn't say _that_ styling is not possible. I meant that based on the way CSS rules are evaluated there is no (yet) standard CSS rule that is applied to descendants of a parent element according to children _count_ of the parent element.

Comment: @Vohuman then I am not sure how can the solution posted below work..?

Comment: The answer, which is indeed a smart one, uses the indices. It's not _count_ based. My comment was somehow confusing and I'll remove it.

Comment: If you're developing an HTML email, be aware that many email clients strip out or ignore <style> css and may listen only to inline css. Running your code through a tool like http://premailer.dialect.ca/ will give you a report of the supported / unsupported breakdown you can expect.

Comment: @dogwoodtree-dot-net Thank you! I have actually discovered that css nth() is not supported in outlook so I had to abandon the solution :-(

Comment: Apologies, I missed the reference to e-mails in the question title before or I would have made mention of the poor support for more advanced CSS in my answer. Will update when I'm back in front of a computer so I can include references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible, yes, but you would need to use multiple selectors, checking the that first cell was also the 4th last cell, the 2nd also the 3rd last, and so on:

```css
.myclass2{
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
}
td:first-child:nth-last-child(4)>.myclass2,
td:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(3)>.myclass2,
td:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(2)>.myclass2,
td:nth-child(4):last-child>.myclass2{
    background:#f00;
}
```

```html
<table class="myclass">
    <tr>
        <td>1 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
        <td>2 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
        <td>3 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="myclass">
    <tr>
        <td>1 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
        <td>2 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
        <td>3 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
        <td>4 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Or, alternatively, just select the first child that is also the fourth last child *and* any cells that follow it:

```css
.myclass2{
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
}
td:first-child:nth-last-child(4)>.myclass2,
td:first-child:nth-last-child(4)~td>.myclass2{
    background:#f00;
}
```

```html
<table class="myclass">
    <tr>
        <td>1 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
        <td>2 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
        <td>3 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="myclass">
    <tr>
        <td>1 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
        <td>2 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
        <td>3 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
        <td>4 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Another way to do it, if you wanted to target rows with any number of cells greater than 3 would be to use the negation pseudo-class to select the first cell that isn't the last, 2nd last or 3rd last cell and all cells that follow it:

```css
.myclass2{
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
}
td:first-child:not(:nth-last-child(-n+3))>.myclass2,
td:first-child:not(:nth-last-child(-n+3))~td>.myclass2{
    background:#f00;
}
```

```html
<table class="myclass">
    <tr>
        <td>1 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
        <td>2 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
        <td>3 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="myclass">
    <tr>
        <td>1 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
        <td>2 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
        <td>3 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
        <td>4 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="myclass">
    <tr>
        <td>1 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
        <td>2 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
        <td>3 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
        <td>4 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
        <td>5 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
        <td>6 <span class="myclass2">xxx</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**NOTE:** These may not be optimal solutions for you, given [the poor support some e-mail clients have for CSS](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).

Comment: This is great! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :) I've updated my answer with a 3rd solution that might be of use to you.

Comment: Thank you! amazing

Comment: this wont work  across all email clients due to the lack of [support](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)  when doing html emails, it is advised to use inline css over "regular css" on `head`  among other [stuff](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/will-it-work/guidelines/)

Comment: Thanks for providing that, @dippas; see my comment on the question made a few minutes ago.

Comment: Inline styles are less important now Gmail supports styles in the head. But nth-chd was probably conceived after Outlook 2003 so email support will be limited