# jquery: do not show specific dropdown menus

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

Some of my main menu items have dropdown menus, some not. I would like to set which ones show up on hover and on click, and which ones do not. In the example below, I would like to forbid first and fourth dropdowns to show up, **because they have only one item.**

```
<div id="main-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://piirissaareturism.ee/avasta-piirissaar/">Avasta Piirissaar</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a rel="bookmark" href="http://piirissaareturism.ee/avasta-piirissaar/welcome-to-your-site">Welcome to Your Site!</a></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="http://piirissaareturism.ee/kasulik-info/">Kasulik info</a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a rel="bookmark" href="http://piirissaareturism.ee/kasulik-info/toitlustus">Toitlustus</a></li>
         <li><a rel="bookmark" href="http://piirissaareturism.ee/kasulik-info/majutus">Majutus</a></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="http://piirissaareturism.ee/puhkajale/">Puhkajale</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://piirissaareturism.ee/meist/">Meist</a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a rel="bookmark" href="http://piirissaareturism.ee/meist/mtu-piirissaare-turism">MTÜ Piirissaare Turism</a></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

I use also jquery to do the following:

first: slide down dropdown on hover

```
$('#main-menu ul li').hover(
  function () {
    $('ul', this).stop(true, true).delay(100).slideDown(300);
  },
  function () {
    $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideUp(300);            
  });
```

second: if menu item has dropdown - show it on click and do not go to item's url, otherwise go to that item's url.

```
$('#main-menu ul li:has(.dropdown-menu)').on('click', function (event) {
  if ($(event.target).parents('ul.dropdown-menu').length > 0) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

I know, my description is abstruse, but look at [my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gallex/6se537er/) to understand better.

Comment: For user experience should the interaction with your dropdown menus not be consistent? Why would you want to have 'onClick' on some and 'hover' on the others?

Comment: Yes, that's what i intend to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`:nth-child()`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector//)** to filter out elements not required,

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6se537er/4/)**

```
$('#main-menu ul li:not(:nth-child(1),:nth-child(4))').hover(
    ...
```

---

For `:first,:last` to work, I had to modify the selector to get only direct descendents.

```
$('#main-menu > ul > li:not(:first,:last)').hover(
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6se537er/6/)**

---

```
$('#main-menu > ul > li:not(:first,:last)').hover(
  function() {
    $('ul', this).stop(true, true).delay(100).slideDown(300);
  },
  function() {
    $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideUp(300);
  });

$('#main-menu > ul > li:not(:first,:last):has(.dropdown-menu)').on('click', function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).parents('ul.dropdown-menu').length > 0) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: For some reason `:last` is not working. Check the updated answer

Comment: thank's Shaunak D, the first request (on hover) has solved! but second - "do not show the dropdown **on click,** but go to that url"

Comment: You have to use same selector for it. It is easy https://jsfiddle.net/6se537er/6/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Shaunak D, could you do this **onclick** solution to site's mobile menu too? [site link](http://piirissaareturism.ee/)

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12198561/3671484 for a great answer on this. It allows you to check for a specific number of children inside a parent

For example it to check for children elements inside a parent:

```
/* two items */
  li:first-child:nth-last-child(2),
  li:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ li {
  width: 50%;
}
```

This checks that the first-child (`li:first-child`) is two sibling elements before the last-child (`:nth-last-child(2))` and also will set the width of this item to 50% along with all of its siblings (`~ li`)