# CSS to target last UL when there is two ULs

Tags: css, css-selectors

Ive looked at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720931/can-css-detect-the-number-of-children-an-element-has).

I'm trying to target the last UL when there is **only** 2 `ul`s, meaning if there is a 3rd `ul` it will not apply.

I've tried:

```
ul:last-child:nth-last-child(2){
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    ....
</ul>
 <ul>
    ....
</ul>
```

But no luck, where am I going wrong?

Comment: You've got them muddled up. The accepted answer to that question pairs :first-child with :nth-last-child(). You're pairing two "last child"s together.

Comment: @BoltClock  I'm guessing we have another misleading question once again

Comment: @dippas: Yeah, it is kinda ambiguous. The asker never stated outright if there's going to be a variable number of ULs. I tend to answer conservatively, i.e. make as few assumptions as possible and try to cover cases where I can't assume. In this case, though, I'm really tempted to just dismiss it as a typo (which is why I've now closed the question as a dupe of the one they linked to).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a combination of last child and second child:

```
ul:last-child:nth-child(2) { ... }
```

Comment: To make this answer complete and more useful, you should explain the logic.

Comment: @Michael_B even the question is ambiguous

Comment: @Michael_B: There's really no need for that when another answer has already done the same, in full, with a few hundred upvotes in tow.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to target the last `UL` when there is **`2 ULs.`**

if you want to target **only** when are 2 `ul` use `last-of-type` or `last-child`

**you don't ask for more than 2 `ul`s**

```css
ul:last-of-type {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
<hr />
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please re-read the question. Only target the last when there are 2.

Comment: there **is only 2**

Comment: This would select the third one if there were 3

Comment: but there is only 2 in the question,

Comment: Yeah, rereading the question it was never implied 2 was a limit, only that there are two and the second one should be selected. I've voted you up to get you back to 0, @panthro should have worded it better.

Comment: Either I don't understand the question, or I don't understand the downvotes.  Any of the downvoters care to explain because this looks like the answer to me.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote