# How set same height for rows

Tags: css, flexbox

How can I set same height for rows in list like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

Elements `<div class="row">` are dynamic genereted and the amount is not constant.

I look for solution in this style:

```
.row {
  height: calc(100% / <amount items>)
}
```

It is possible to get amount items in CSS?

I use flexbox.

Comment: Does it have to be a css solution? or can it be js as well

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720931/can-css-detect-the-number-of-children-an-element-has , but you will have to manually add styles for each amount.

Comment: you will get same height for rows in the flex-direction as default `align-items` value is `stretch`