# Hide only Last Element if Parent has (15,45,75,105) Elements (CSS Only)

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list `<ul>` which can have **15**,30,**45**,60,**75**,90,... and so on elements in it. I want to hide only last element if the list has *15 / 45 / 75 / 105* and so on. I want to do it with **CSS only**, no JQuery etc.

I tried my level best to accomplish it and found this article 
[Can CSS detect the number of children an element has?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720931/can-css-detect-the-number-of-children-an-element-has) so far but could not get to work it.

How can I get this job done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:last-child` and `:nth-child`:

```
ul :last-child:nth-child(30n+15)
{ 
    display: none; 
}
```

Demo (using 3/9/15 here instead because I don't want to paste too many li)

```css
ul :last-child:nth-child(6n+3) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1st child</li>
  <li>1st child</li>
  <li>1st child</li>
  <li>1st child</li>
  <li>1st child</li>
  <li>1st child</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>1st child</li>
  <li>1st child</li>
  <li>1st child</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No, This hides 30,60,90 also. While I want to hide only 15,45,75,105,135 and so on –

Comment: @AbdulJabbarWebBestow Please check my editted answer

Comment: ul :last-child:nth-child(30n-15) is working instead of + I used - and now its working.

Comment: Eh are you sure? I'm quite sure + and - are both the same. When `n=0` => `30n+15` is 15.

Comment: Ohhh Yes sure. I made a mistake. Thanks. You are right

Answer (score 4):

Combine [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) with [`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) :

```
ul > li:last-child:nth-of-type(15n):not(:nth-of-type(30n)) { display: none; }
```

Comment: No, This hides 30,60,90 also. While I want to hide only 15,45,75,105,135 and so on

Comment: Excellent. Now it's Working Great. Thanks @wscourge.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for not reading too carefully at the first time. Happy to help.