# Applying styles to the child of an adjacent sibling

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm attempting to resize images in a row with CSS, based on how many images are in the same row. For example, if there are four `img` elements in the same `p`, they are styled a certain way. Here is the working code, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12198561/2255592):

**HTML:**

```
<p>
  <img src="preview.png">
  <img src="preview.png">
  <img src="preview.png">
  <img src="preview.png">
</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
.post-content p img:first-child:nth-last-child(4),
.post-content p img:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ img {
    width: 25%; /* fallback for browsers that don't support calc */
    width: calc((100% / 4) - 0.8%);
    margin-left: calc(1%);
}

.post-content p img:first-child:nth-last-child(4) { /* First image in group of four */
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

However, this does not work for images wrapped in `a` tags, but with the rest of the formatting identical, like this:

```
<p>
  <a href="#"><img src="preview.png"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="preview.png"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="preview.png"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="preview.png"></a>
</p>
```

I am unable to find a solution in this case. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `:nth-child()`'s, `:first-child`'s, and sibling selector need to be based off of the `a` tags, since those are the children and siblings, then the selectors should end with `img` to target the CSS property of the image.

```css
p a:first-child:nth-last-child(4) img,
p a:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ a img {
    width: 25%;
    width: calc((100% / 4) - 0.8%);
    margin-left: calc(1%);
}

p a:first-child:nth-last-child(4) img {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png"></a><a href="#"><img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png"></a><a href="#"><img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png"></a><a href="#"><img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png"></a>
</p>
```

Comment: @user2255592 awesome np :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing the `img` with an `a` before `first-child` in your CSS? That is,

```
.post-content p a:first-child:nth-last-child(4) img,
.post-content p a:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ a img {
    width: 25%;
    width: calc((100% / 4) - 0.8%);
    margin-left: calc(1%);
}

.post-content p a:first-child:nth-last-child(4) img {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I have. The problem is that the CSS then determines styles based on how many elements are in <a>, and not how many elements are in the parent of <a>. Since each <a> only has one child, it doesn't work.