# select parent element based on number of children it has

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a way to select the `TR` with 2 `TD's` in it?

I want to achieve it using pure css. I will use jQuery or javascript, but i want to make sure that this is absolutely not possible using plain CSS before moving to `jQuery`

For example in jQuery, you have

```
$("tr").each(function(){
if($(this).children().find("td").length==2){
  $(this).css({some properties});
}
})
```

Can something similar to this be achieved using `CSS`?

Comment: Please add you code.

Comment: @Kobi, the question you marked as duplicate is not relative to the topic

Comment: duplicate off https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720931/can-css-detect-the-number-of-children-an-element-has

Comment: @KAD - It certainly is. There are no parent selectors at all (yet). If there were, you would be able to use `nth-child` (or `+`, and/or `:not`) to count children.

Comment: @ShyamShingadiya i have added jquery code, looking to achieve similar using plain css

Comment: @Kobi, the question you linked asks if you can select a parent based on a child element specifying certain element types. This question asks about an abstract theory to select a parent based on the number of children independent of types

Comment: @vignesh, I am not sure but this is something can help you. `tr td:nth-child(-n+2){
    border:1px solid black;
}`

Comment: re-opening the questions for votes @ShyamShingadiya thanks, I am actually looking to apply style to TR based on number of TDs.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot select a parent based on the number of children it has in css, you can only apply styles to nodes based on their siblings. So this is not feasible in your case.

Comment: please delete the answer i need to delete the question

Comment: Its a valid question, you just have to edit it to view the code and make it clear