# Flexbox columns to have boxes that are half the size of the other ones

Tags: css, flexbox

I have 4 to 8 columns in a row, and I don't know their size. I want 2 of the columns to be half the width as the other ones without knowing how many columns there are in total. How would I do this with flexbox? Thanks.

So i.e. 5 columns should be

```
[ 1   12.5% ] [ 2   12.5% ] [ 3   25% ] [ 4   25% ] [ 4   25% ]
```

Comment: This question is somewhat unclear. Can you post more details and maybe an illustration? The code you've tried would be good, too.

Comment: I updated you question how I understood you meant. If that became wrong, please let me know and I'll adjust, or delete, both the edit and my posted answer

Comment: @LGSon that's correct ty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is 2 ways to do this with Flexbox, where one either use `flex-grow` or `flex-basis`.

With `flex-grow` one simply set the first 2 elements to `1`, which mean they will take equal size of the remaining space, and then set `2` for the 3-8 elements, which means they should take twice the size of the first 2.

The downside with this is that the *remaining space* is based on what's left of the space *after* what the content in each element consume.

This can be seen in the first 2 rows (lightblue).

---

If a more exact size is required, `flex-basis` can do that, and here combined with an adjusted verstion of the [can-css-detect-the-number-of-children-an-element-has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720931/can-css-detect-the-number-of-children-an-element-has) trick.

The beauty with this is, you can make them behave different based on how many there are.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z1pkye0v/1/)

```css
/*  using flex-grow  */
.test1 .flexparent div:nth-child(1),
.test1 .flexparent div:nth-child(2) {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #aaf;
}
.test1 .flexparent div:nth-child(n+3) {
  flex-grow: 2;
}

/*  using flex-basis  */
/* four items, first 2 */
.test2 .flexparent div:first-child:nth-last-child(4),
.test2 .flexparent div:first-child:nth-last-child(4) + div {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 3 / 2);
  background: #0c0;
}
/* four items, last 2 */
.test2 .flexparent div:first-child:nth-last-child(4)  + div ~ div {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 3);
}
/* five items, first 2 */
.test2 .flexparent div:first-child:nth-last-child(5),
.test2 .flexparent div:first-child:nth-last-child(5) + div {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 4 / 2);
  background: #0b0;
}
/* five items, last 3 */
.test2 .flexparent div:first-child:nth-last-child(5)  + div ~ div {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 4);
}
/* six items, first 2 */
.test2 .flexparent div:first-child:nth-last-child(6),
.test2 .flexparent div:first-child:nth-last-child(6) + div {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 5 / 2);
  background: #0a0;
}
/* six items, last 4 */
.test2 .flexparent div:first-child:nth-last-child(6)  + div ~ div {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 5);
}
/* seven items, first 2 */
.test2 .flexparent div:first-child:nth-last-child(7),
.test2 .flexparent div:first-child:nth-last-child(7) + div {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 6 / 2);
  background: #090;
}
/* seven items, last 5 */
.test2 .flexparent div:first-child:nth-last-child(7)  + div ~ div {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 6);
}
/* eight items, first 2 */
.test2 .flexparent div:first-child:nth-last-child(8),
.test2 .flexparent div:first-child:nth-last-child(8) + div {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 7 / 2);
  background: #080;
}
/* eight items, last 6 */
.test2 .flexparent div:first-child:nth-last-child(8)  + div ~ div {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 7);
}

/* general styles */
.flexparent {
  display: flex;
}
.flexparent.nr2, .test2 {
  margin-top: 4px;
}
.flexparent div {
  min-width: 0;                     /*  allow a flex item to shrink below its content  */
  margin: 0 2px;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightblue;
}
.test2 .flexparent div {
  background: lightgreen;
}
.flexparent div {
  padding: 2px 0;
}
.flexparent div:empty {
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">
 <div class="flexparent">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
 </div>
 <div class="flexparent nr2">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="test2">
 <div class="flexparent">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
 </div>
 <div class="flexparent nr2">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
 </div>
 <div class="flexparent nr2">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
 </div>
 <div class="flexparent nr2">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
 </div>
 <div class="flexparent nr2">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
 </div>
 <div class="flexparent nr2">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

---

In addition to [YD1m's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44772628/flexbox-columns-to-have-boxes-that-are-half-the-size-of-the-other-ones/44776020#44776020), one doesn't need to wrap the 2 first elements, simply set their `flex-basis`, where the first 2 gets `50%` and the rest `100%`.

This works like so, as the sum of their set `flex-basis` is wider than their parent, they will not fit, and because `flex-shrink` defaults to `1` they will shrink equally. (and since there is no space left, `flex-grow` doesn't have any effect)

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z1pkye0v/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the first two columns in a container container which is equal to the width of the other columns.

```
[[ x / 2 ] [ x / 2 ]] [         x         ] [         x         ]
          x
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-content: stretch;
  text-align: center;
}

.main > div {  
  flex: 1 1 100%;        
}

.main > div:not(.wrapper) {
  background: gray;
  margin: 0 2px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper .half {  
  background: red;  
  flex: 1 1 50%;  
  margin: 0 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="half">1</div>
        <div class="half">2</div>
    </div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't even think to do it this way...nice plus 1.