# auto columns to have each LI of UL justified on a single line

Tags: css, css-multicolumn-layout

I have an unordered list with a number of list elements.  I don't know the exact number of `li` elements in said `ul` -- e.g., it could either be 3 or 4 elements (all very concise ones) -- but I `display` each `li` as a `block` (not as an actual list), and want to use the `columns` feature to set it all on one line, equally centred / justified.

However, if I do `columns: 4`, and only have 3 elements, then they're displayed as if a fourth element is missing.  Is there a way for them to be displayed as if `columns: 3` has been specified?  (I've tried setting columns to `auto`, but it didn't seem to do anything in the browser I tested.)

Basically, I want the `columns` CSS property of `ul` to be set to the number of `li` children that the `ul` has, in CSS.

Comment: can you show what have you done so far?

Comment: @ShadowFiend, it's [here](http://reg.su/?SO/46148121); i want to add a fourth element depending on condition, but have static CSS that works with 3 or 4 elements equally well

Comment: i mean the code?

Answer (score 0):

By changing the display property of li element,you can make this (3 or 4 lis) center aligned of your window.

```css
ul#registrar {
    text-align: center;
}
ul#registrar li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="registrar">
<li><a href="/reg.com">reg.com</a></li>
<li><a href="/reg.ru">reg.ru</a></li>
<li><a href="/nic.ru">nic.ru</a></li><li><a href="/nic.ru">nic.ru</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I see; looks like `inline-block`, together with https://stackoverflow.com/a/12198561/1122270, should do the trick.  (But by itself your code doesn't work as expected — as I want each `li` to be evenly spaced.)

Comment: So have you tried inline-block with [above mentioned link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720931/can-css-detect-the-number-of-children-an-element-has/12198561#12198561) ?