# window.print() set a table fit in page

Tags: javascript, html

This is how it looks my HTML:

[image: Html]

In order to print the page I am using in JavaScript the `window.print()` function.

```
$scope.print= function() {
    $("#tab2-panel-tools").hide();
    $("#title-row").hide();
    window.print();
    $("#tab2-panel-tools").show();
    $("#title-row").show();
}
```

In the next image is my print preview. In the print preview the table exceed the width of the page. How can I fit the table in the page?
[image: print preview]

Comment: Make a pdf in landscape

Comment: Make it smaller?

Comment: How can I make it smaller only in the print preview?

Comment: Change the `scale` in settings (click `more settings` on the left) to print it smaller. Would be better in `landscape` -- change it in settings too.

Answer (score 4):

You can solve it with css, to set a new style for your printed versions, use [media print](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)

```
@media print {
  table{
    font-size: 10px;//customize your table so they can fit
  }
}
```

Comment: my table can has different number of columns and rows. Can i set the table to fit in page according to number of columns? ... for example there are situation when i have 10 columns, then i can set bigger font-size... also there are situations when i have 20 columns then i need to set smaller font-size... this is my big problem

Comment: I would recommend to open a new question for this but basically you can play with JavaScript to detect the number of columns and add an specific class or you can try with pure css as it is explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12198561/2894798

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, using javascript, here is my code:

```
    $scope.print= function() {
    var nrColumns = $("#reportPrintPreviewTableBody tr:first td").length;
    //here I can put as many "if"-s as I need
    if (nrColumns >= 14) {
        $("#reportPrintPreviewTable").css("font-size", "10px");
    }else if (nrColumns >= 10) {
        $("#reportPrintPreviewTable").css("font-size", "14px");
    }

    //$("#reportPrintPreviewTable").css("height", "100%");
    $("#tab2-panel-tools").hide();
    $("#title-row").hide();
    window.print();
    $("#reportPrintPreviewTable").css("font-size", "11px");
    $("#tab2-panel-tools").show();
    $("#title-row").show();
}
```