# Set td width by td number in a table

Tags: html, css, html-table

Is there a way to set `td` width by number of `td` in a table. e.g:

- if there is 1 `td`, then the width of each `td` is 100%
- if there is 2 `td`, then the width of each `td` is 50%
- if there is 3 `td`, then the width of each `td` is 1/3
- etc.

**Is there a way to write a CSS rule for this need?**

Side note: I can not edit the HTML, it comes from somwhere else. I can only edit CSS.

The HTML could look like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>bar</td>
    <td>baz<td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: And I assume you cant use jquery or javascript either?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720931/can-css-detect-the-number-of-children-an-element-has

Comment: That HTML would be invalid. It lacks a closing `</td>` for the 3rd cell, and the `<tr>` is also never closed.

Comment: @TimGerhard You are right.

Comment: @connexo Woops! fixed, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `table-layout:fixed` with `width:100%`  to the `table`.

***table-layout: fixed***

> *[Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col elements or by the width of the first row of cells](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout)*

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>bar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>bar</td>
    <td>baztd</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo</td>
    <td>bar</td>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>bar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```