# Same size tabs in bulma

Tags: html, css, bulma

I'm using [Bulma](https://bulma.io/documentation/components/tabs/) and I have some tabs with the is-fullwidth option, however, each tab takes a different width depending on the content. I would like all tabs to keep the same size (using ellipsis on text that is too long), preferable avoiding Javascript.

An example of my tabs would be

```
<div class="tabs is-fullwidth">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>
        First
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>
       A very long thing with a lot of text
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>
        Third
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Edit**
The number of tabs may change (between 1 and 6) depending on the user config

Answer (score 1):

try it, you can use `text-overflow` and `overflow` to fix it.

https://jsfiddle.net/4kjvq7xp/

```css
li {
    width: 33.333%;
}

span {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bulma.io/css/bulma-docs.min.css?v=201806071228">
<script defer="" src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"></script>
<div class="tabs is-fullwidth">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>
        <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <span>Left</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>
        <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-angle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <span>A very long thing with a lot of text</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>
        <span>Right</span>
        <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I forgot to mention the number of tabs can vary (from 1 to 6)

Comment: Modify width of li to 16.66%(100/6)

Comment: hardcoded number wont work, as the number of tabs change according to the user, I would prefer to stick to css (so no javascript to change the width) if possible

Comment: you can check this article [Can CSS detect the number of children an element has?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12198561/7291379) to dynamic apply your width