# Dynamically increase and decrease an input text box size depending on another selector width

Tags: javascript, css

I have an `input text box` which has some padding to it. I also have a `wrapper` class selector which is used next to that `input text box`. I am trying to remove `set` `padding` from the input text box and make that space dynamic so that the element size would (especially width) increase and decrease depending on the `screen size` (i.e. Mobile or Large view as large screen) without effecting the `wrapper`.

The text box looks like the following. a, c, d, e are buttons which appear dynamically. So the space for **b** here should expand if the there is only one button on the right and decrease if there are all the buttons on the right.

|____|________________________ |_____|_____|_____|

`a                 b                  c     d     e`

so the css class selectors that I have includes b and another one includes all the c, d, e (wrapper).

I assume this can't only be done through `CSS`. Any suggestion?

**CSS:**

```
 .input {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: var(--grid-main-max-width);
  padding: 1.188rem 2.9rem 1.188rem 4.5rem;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid var(--color-gray);
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
  outline: 0;
  }


.wrapper {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 1.5rem;
bottom: 0;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
<input class="input">
  <div class= "wrapper">
  <button>c</button>
  <button>d</button>
  <button>e</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Look into [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Comment: @ScottMarcus I already use `Media Queries` for different screen size. The issue is not this. The issue is to make the input text box dynamic.

Comment: That is exactly what Media Queries are for.

Comment: @Amessihel let me get my solution working first with your ideas. Only then I can accept this as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution only needed to count the `width` of the `input` `text box` and the `wrapper` and assign the difference as a padding to the right of the `input` text box. The following little change was added to an `onInput` event.

```
document.getElemendById("inputTextBox").style.paddingRight = document.getElemendById("searchFieldWrapper").clientWidth;
```

And also needed to use `Media Queries` for `@media (--large-viewport)` / `@media (--medium-viewport)` to assign different `padding` for the `input`. as @Scott Marcus mentioned in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have `div` child blocks for those child elements or you can specify some class.

```
div:first-child:nth-last-child(1){
    width: 100%;
}

div:first-child:nth-last-child(2),
div:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ div{
    width: 50%;
}

div:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
div:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ div{
    width: 33.3%;
}

div:first-child:nth-last-child(4), 
div:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ div{
    width: 25%;
}
//and so on
```

Source [refer to here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720931/can-css-detect-the-number-of-children-an-element-has)

Also if you want to modify other elements you can use

```
div:first-child:nth-last-child(2) > .someClass{
    style:goesHere
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*(**UPDATE**: I figured out you used a wrapper element, and that `a` is'nt a label but a button. But this answer is easily adaptable to your question.)*

You can use the `calc` function provided by CSS. Given this piece of HTML (I joined all the elements to remove side effects of the blank characters; we can fix it in an [other way](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) but I wanted to keep the answer simple):

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <article id="demo">
      <label>a</label><input type="text" placeholder="b" /><button>c</button><button>d</button><button>e</button>
    </article>
  </body>
</html>
```

This piece of CSS allow the input text element to fill the available space.

```
article#demo {
  /* the width (80vw) includes border and padding */
  width: 80vw;
}

article#demo label {
  /* to make label resizable */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
}

article#demo button {
  width: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f0f0ff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* see above */
}

article#demo input[type="text"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* text input width = 100% minus other items */
  width: calc(100% - 30px - 3 * 20px);
}
```

You can set the width of `article#demo` using any unit (`em`, `ex`, etc.) it should work.

In your final design, use `box-sizing:border-box` to set the whole element, including borders and padding, within the CSS `width`. Otherwise, you'll have to adjust the `calc` parameter.

If you put left or right margins, count them too.

If you use font-dependent units (`em`, etc.), the same `font-family` and other font-related CSS entries have to be set - implicitly or not - for all the concerned elements.

Working fiddle with a little interactive test [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yaeh8cz0/9).

Comment: The buttons seem static in your solution. The input text search box needs to dynamically change size without any button click which you have the `onClick` event.

Comment: The onClick is just here for the demo. You can resize manually the fiddle frame to see the changes. The size of the buttons doesn't change, yes, I understood you wanted a dynamic width for your text input, am I wrong ?

Comment: Correct about the dynamic width for text input