# Is it possible to arrange items in two rows without the use of an intermediate div?

Tags: css, position

```css
img {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg"/>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg"/>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg"/>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg"/>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I managed to arrange the images in two rows however, this required putting them into two two `div`s. Now the items are dynamically generated and their number is not known upfront. Clearly it's not difficult to write JS that will arrange the items correctly into these two divs however, I'm interested if I can avoid this nonetheless?

Namely, I'm interested if I can write CSS that will arrange all items into evenly-sized rows (that is, eg 4 items in one row nad 4 in the other, not 6 in one row and 2 in the other) without the use of the intermediate divs? So that all `img`s will be direct children of the outermost `div` only and once their number changes (some are added, some are removed) they will rearrange themselves properly without any extra JS code to rearrange them into `div`s or to change class or inline style of, say, the `n/2`th `img`?

EDIT: Just like in my snippet I want the images to occupy only as much horizontal space as necessary and NOT to stretch to the full width of the enclosing container. This is actually required.

Comment: can you wrap each img in a `div` ? If you can it will be easier

Comment: @Viira why not?

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: @Pete hmm OK but isnt br Considered Harmful™? This is at least what I seem to recall

Comment: You can use Flexbox + a pseudo as a delimiter: https://jsfiddle.net/8u6sjo3t/ ... and then reposition the pseudo (or both pseudo for 3 rows) with e.g. media query's

Comment: @Pete Enforcing appearance with HTML. No semantic meaning of the tag. Appearance and item arrangement are CSS's thing, doing this in HTML is a Bad Thing™, so font tags, table tags for non-tabular data, the center tag, br, etc are all out. (Br might be OK for poetry when line breaks do have semantic meaning, but that's it). That's at least what was hammered to my mind a few years ago.

Comment: And if you don't want to use a pseudo, add an empty element and use that as a delimiter: https://jsfiddle.net/8u6sjo3t/1/ ... With these options you have full control on how to order the items.

Comment: @LGSon A nice fiddle, thank you. The problem of it (and all 2 answers) is that if the number of imgs changes some custom JS will have to modify inline CSS so that the break is at the correct place... But I'll guess its unavoidable?

Comment: No, you can actually use CSS to detect the amount of children as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720931/can-css-detect-the-number-of-children-an-element-has

Comment: And here is 3 markup samples showing "how-to" using your requirement: https://jsfiddle.net/8u6sjo3t/2/

Comment: And this sample show the same but with uneven items: https://jsfiddle.net/8u6sjo3t/3/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pseudo-element to create a break:

```css
.container>span:nth-child(3n):after {
  content: "\A";
  display: block;
}

img {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg" /></span>
  <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg" /></span>
  <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg" /></span>
  <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg" /></span>
  <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg" /></span>
  <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg" /></span>
  <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg" /></span>
  <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg" /></span>
  <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg" /></span>
</div>
```

If you want 4 on a line, you would use `4n`

Comment: Yes but now the images stretch to the full width of the enclosing container. I wanted to avoid that. I wanted them to occupy only as much horizontal space as necessary. Like I showed in my snippet. Perhaps I didn't emphasise this enough in my Q, I'm sorry for that.

Comment: With that you might end up with issues if to style the `span` ... feel free to use my fiddle sample I posted in my comments at the question ... after all, they were a small extension of your initial code sample :)

Comment: @LGSon unfortunately your fiddle would only work if there are 2 rows

Comment: No, it works for 3 using both pseudo ... still, OP asks for 2 ... and my second sample use an empty span, were one can add as many as needed.

Comment: A nice answer, thank you. The problem of it is that if the number of imgs changes some custom JS will have to modify inline CSS so that the break is at the correct place... But I'll guess its unavoidable?

Answer (score 0):

Using [CSS `grid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) you could:

```css
div{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 50px);
}
img {
  width: 100%; /* as the column width */
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg"/>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg"/>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg"/>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg"/>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg"/>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: A nice answer, thank you. The added benefit is that if one of the imgs is larger it won't break the layout. I think I'd like `inline-grid` more though, tho its a minor modification. The problem of it is that if the number of imgs changes some custom JS will have to modify inline CSS so that the break is at the correct place... But I'll guess its unavoidable?

Comment: "The added benefit is that if one of the imgs is larger it won't break the layout." Ugh, only if `min-content` is used instead of `50px`

Comment: @gaazkam you can always use `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);` - so `auto` instead of the hardcoded `50px`

Answer (score 0):

The solution that seems closest to what I need: (It's a slightly modified version of Roko C. Buljan's solution, so much of the credit goes to him ☺ )

```css
div{
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, max-content); 
}
img {
  width: 50px;
}
img:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg"/>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg"/>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg"/>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg"/>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg"/>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg"/>
</div>
```

That way the whole grid container's width will not exceed what's necessary and one larger element won't screw layout . `grid-template-columns` will have to be set from JS though (since it depends on how many elements we have), but I guess it's unavoidable really ☹ )