# add style to ALL child elements using plain javascript (multiple containers)

Tags: javascript, html

What i need is a different el.style.height depends on amount of child nodes.. So for example in a second div with class links -> a tags should have style="height: 100px";
I have build this:

```js
function sameHeightLinks() {
  var linkContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.links');
  for (var i = 0; i < linkContainers.length; i++) {
    var linkContainer = linkContainers[i];
    var linkItself = linkContainer.children[0];
    var linksAmount = linkContainer.childElementCount;
    if (linksAmount == 2) {
      linkItself.style.height = '59.5px';
    }
  }
}
sameHeightLinks();
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a>Some link</a>
  <a>Some link</a>
  <a>Some link</a>
  <a>Some link</a>
</div>
<div class="links">
  <a>Some link</a>
  <a>Some link</a>
</div>
<div class="links">
  <a>Some link</a>
  <a>Some link</a>
  <a>Some link</a>
</div>
```

As you may see it works because im targeting only first child node here.
But as soon as im trying add additional for cycle in order to go through all a tags -> it does not work..
What would be the right syntax in this specific case? Im sure that there should be 2 for cycles. But i think that i just cant get "ALL children" right..

PS: IE 11 support is required

Comment: Do you have to do this with javascript? Why not use a static CSS? This is after all what CSS is intended for.

Comment: yeah. and i would love to use CSS. It would be 2 min fix. But i cant (in this specific case).

Comment: Why cant you use CSS?

Comment: because i have not just 3 divs. Lets say that divs amount is somewhere around 50 + they have different amount of links each time when page is recreated (new data was added - old data removed). So for you page can show first div with 3 links (in this period of time). But for someone else first div will contain 5 links.

Comment: What logic do you have for determining which "links" div should have what styles?

Comment: I'm still a little confused about what your expected output is. You can possibly consider using a more specific selector in `querySelectorAll()`. I created a [code snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/khan_y/2c0es75m/8/) where I revised your function to select all links.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
function sameHeightLinks() {
  const linkContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.links');
  linkContainers.forEach(container => {
    if (container.childElementCount === 2) {
      for (let i=0; i < container.children.length; i++) {
        container.children[i].style.height = '59.5px';
      }
    }
  });
}
sameHeightLinks();
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a>Some link</a>
  <a>Some link</a>
  <a>Some link</a>
  <a>Some link</a>
</div>
<div class="links">
  <a>Some link</a>
  <a>Some link</a>
</div>
<div class="links">
  <a>Some link</a>
  <a>Some link</a>
  <a>Some link</a>
</div>
```

Without forEach:

```js
function sameHeightLinks() {
  const linkContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.links');
  for (let i=0; i < linkContainers.length; i++) {
    const container = linkContainers[i];
    if (container.childElementCount === 2) {
      for (let i=0; i < container.children.length; i++) {
        container.children[i].style.height = '59.5px';
      }
    }
  }
}
sameHeightLinks();
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a>Some link</a>
  <a>Some link</a>
  <a>Some link</a>
  <a>Some link</a>
</div>
<div class="links">
  <a>Some link</a>
  <a>Some link</a>
</div>
<div class="links">
  <a>Some link</a>
  <a>Some link</a>
  <a>Some link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: my bad..IE 11 support is required....
forEach does not work in IE11
But you solution is great.

Comment: Ah no problem! I've updated my answer. I changed the original to forEach because I just think it looks cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the only logic determining if the children of a div should be styled, is the number of children of that div. If that's the case then you could use this trick i found in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12198561/6224823) about selecting elements based on their children.

The solution is just a slightly complex CSS selector. No javascript required.

And it works in IE11, see [first-child](https://caniuse.com/#search=first-child), [nth-last-child](https://caniuse.com/#search=nth-last-child), [Child combinator](https://caniuse.com/#search=Child%20combinator) & [General sibling combinator](https://caniuse.com/#search=~)

```css
.links > a:first-child:nth-last-child(2),
.links > a:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ a {
    height: 59.5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a>Some link</a>
  <a>Some link</a>
  <a>Some link</a>
  <a>Some link</a>
</div>
<div class="links">
  <a>Some link</a>
  <a>Some link</a>
</div>
<div class="links">
  <a>Some link</a>
  <a>Some link</a>
  <a>Some link</a>
</div>
```