# CSS selector that selects an element if it contains ONLY another element, without any other texts

Tags: html, css, beautifulsoup

How can I select an element, say `<p>`, that only contains another element, say `<a>`, inside it, and nothing else, like this: `<p><a>Some text</a></p>`? In contrast, I don't want to select things like `<p>Some other text<a>Some text</a></p>`, since there are stuff outside the `<a>` element.

I tried the CSS selector `p:has(a)`, but this selects both of the cases above. Is there a CSS selector that only selects the first case and not the undesirable second case? Thank you.

For reference, I'm using Soup Sieve's [CSS selectors](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can CSS detect the number of children an element has?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720931/can-css-detect-the-number-of-children-an-element-has)

Comment: Thank you for your help. The proposed solution in the link works if there is another element outside `a`, but does not seem to work when there is only text outside `a`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `>` to select immediate children, and `:only-child` to select the `p` element only when its the only child.

```
p > a:only-child {
  color: red;
}
```

Working example: codepen.io/srikanthps/pen/Exaqoew

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried this method but it seems it will select both cases, since in the second case, `a` is still the only child of `p`.

Comment: I tested - https://codepen.io/srikanthps/pen/Exaqoew - it seems to do what you asked for in your query.

Comment: @WandMaker It doesn't, try adding this 2 codes `<p><a>Some text</a></p>` and `<p>test <a>Some text</a></p>`. You'll notice both `a` becomes red.

Comment: Would be nice if you'd add some explanation about the code

Comment: I tried your code on jsfiddle. It didn't work, but yes on your codepen it works. I am confused. Haha

Comment: Thank you @WandMaker. This sadly doesn't seem to work with [BeautifulSoup](https://i.imgur.com/hD6rO2N.png), however.

Comment: 1. OP is right, the `codepen` result is malformed, cuz there are many incompleted tags `</p`... \
1. OP wants to select the parent, not the child -- something more like `p:has(> a:only-child)` (but this still wont work as OP expected) \
1. I dont think what OP trying to achieve (-- by using css to detect text (/textNode) inside an element) is possible (in most browsers). May need to use Javascript. \
1. Try **`p:has(> a:only-child:-moz-last-node:-moz-first-node)`** in mozilla, this should work.