# how to distribute elements vertically evenly while keeping free float using CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to distribute elements of a list vertically evenly while keeping them floating. The count of elements is dynamic, so is there string length. The height of the surrounding container is static. Here's an example:

```
----------------------------------
| element1 | element2 | element3 |
|                                |
| el4 | el5 | element6 | elem7   |
|                                |
| el8 | element9 | element10     |
|                                |
|                                |
|                                |
----------------------------------
```

This is desired:

```
----------------------------------
| element1 | element2 | element3 |
|                                |
|                                |
| el4 | el5 | element6 | elem7   |
|                                |
|                                |
| el8 | element9 | element10     |
|                                |
----------------------------------
```

As I don't know how many elements are in the container, I can't distribute them into table rows. As you can see in the example, line 2 contains 4 elements whereas line 1 and 3 carry 3 elements.
I tried working with `line-height` but that's not dynamic. If I get more elements, line-height would have to decrease accordingly.

I thought about detecting the element count as in [Can CSS detect the number of children an element has?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720931/can-css-detect-the-number-of-children-an-element-has) but that doesn't cover different widths of the elements. The pure count doesn't help here.

Any ideas on how to solve that problem using pure CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Set the following props to parent container

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-items: space-between;
```

Comment: Shouldn't this rather be `align-content` instead of `align-items`?

Answer (score 0):

I leave you two examples of Flex.

I don't know what you want exactly.
The javascript is just to give you a random size for the test.

I've gotten too much, you can remove some properties.

```js
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var i in a){
  if(!a.hasOwnProperty(i)){continue;}
  if(i == 0){continue;}
  a[i].style.minWidth = Math.floor(Math.random()*200+100) +  "px";
  a[i].style.height = Math.floor(Math.random()*20+5) +  "px";
}
```

```css
div div{
  border: 1px solid;
  display: block;
  background-color: #66F;

}
.container{
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}
.container > div{
  margin: 5px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

```js
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var i in a){
  if(!a.hasOwnProperty(i)){continue;}
  if(i == 0){continue;}
  a[i].style.minWidth = Math.floor(Math.random()*200+100) +  "px";
  a[i].style.height = Math.floor(Math.random()*20+5) +  "px";
}
```

```css
div div{
  border: 1px solid;
  display: block;
  background-color: #66F;
}
.container{
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}
.container > div{
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```