# Expand CSS grid items based on number child elements

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm aware can set the number of columns a grid item spans using:

```css
grid-column: span 2;
```

But is it possible to have CSS grid do this automatically *only* if there is space available?

So in the case of the mockup below, if there are three items they each take up a full column, but if there are two, the last item will expand to fill up the empty column.

[image]

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 25px;
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 50px;
  color: white;
  background-color: lightpink;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>

<br />
<hr />
<br />

<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item">I should take up two columns</div>
</div>
```

Comment: not with grid only with flexbox by using `flex-grow`

Comment: Perhaps try nth-child? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720931/can-css-detect-the-number-of-children-an-element-has

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding and using `span 2` (which is useful sometimes) you can use `grid-column: 2 / -1;`. It says that your grid column should start from the second col and should span until it has the space (exactly what you want)

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 25px;
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 50px;
  color: white;
  background-color: lightpink;
}

.grid-item-2 {
  grid-column: 2 / -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>

<br />
<hr />
<br />

<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-2">I should take up two columns</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its almost the right answer, but what a pity that you solution only works when you know the number of items, which defeats the purpose.
Here is a fix that works without tagging the 2nd element: 
.grid-item:nth-child(2){ grid-column-start: 2 }
.grid-item:last-child{ grid-column-end: -1 }