# Avoid dot in unordered-list if there is only one item. Pure CSS?

Tags: css

Is there a way to hide the bullet-point of `<ul>...</ul>` if there is only one item?

Example, here I want to have bullet-points:

```
<ul><li>foo</li><li>bar</li></ul>
```

```
* foo
* bar
```

Here, I don't want a bullet-point:

```
<ul><li>foo</li></ul>
```

```
foo
```

Is there a pure css solution?

Comment: have you seen the answer in :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720931/can-css-detect-the-number-of-children-an-element-has
it might be helpful

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`:only-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child) for that.

```css
li {
  list-style: disc;
}

li:only-child {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
</ul>


<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:only-child` or `:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(1)`:

```css
li:only-child {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul><li>foo</li><li>bar</li></ul>

<ul><li>foo</li></ul>
```

Unfortunately, you cannot target the `ul`, only the `li` with this method.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```css
/* one item */

li:first-child:nth-last-child(1) {
  /* -or- li:only-child { */
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
2 items
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
</ul>

Only one
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
</ul>

3 items
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
  <li>bar</li>
</ul>

4 items
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
  <li>bar</li>
  <li>bar</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have astutely pointed out, you can use pseudo CSS classes.

A simple method if say you know the first bullet as in your example, `foo`, should always never have a bullet is `first-child` see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child

If it's the second, third, fourth, or every other one see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

For targeting a specific `<li>` see above.