# Locate element with specific number of child elements

Tags: javascript, playwright

Let's say I have two lists on the page, one with a single item and one with two:

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
</ul>
```

I know I can find the `ul` that has the "Two" `li`, like so:

```
 page.locator('ul', {has: page.locator('li:text("Two")')});
```

But is there any way to find the `ul` that has *two* `li`s?  Something like:

```
 page.locator('ul', {hasCount: [page.locator('li'),2]});
```

Comment: Can you provide more context as to why you need to do this? There [may be a better way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). There is a `toHaveCount()` matcher that should work for this, but it's not clear whether you're testing or what. Does this need auto-waiting?

Comment: I have two elements (not `<ul>`s, but the tag's not important) that are indistinguishable from each other, except that one has multiple `<tspan>` elements, and the other only has one.  I want to get the one that has only a single `<tspan>`, but when I try to locate it I inevitably get the other.  I'm not looking to throw out the selection work I've already done (it took a lot of work just to get to these two), I just want to differentiate them ... but the only way to do that is by comparing their child count.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. The comment says you want the one with 1 child, but the post body says you want the one with 2 children. Which are you trying to get? Usually, there are elegant and simple ways to do most things, so if you find you're doing a huge amount of work, there may be a better way, but there's no way to solve that problem without details. (We've had this discussion a few times in your other posts, so I'll refer to those... same basic problem for all of the posts--I can maybe hack together a poor solution to problem Y, but it's probably not a suitable one for your real problem X)

Comment: I'm just looking for the mechanism for locating (or filtering) elements based on their child count in Playwright.  That mechanism will presumably be the same whether I want to select an element with one child, two, or five hundred.

Comment: I understand what you want. It's just an unusual thing to want to do, and it isn't built into Playwright as far as I know. There's probably a better, non-hacky way to select those elements or achieve whatever you're actually trying to achieve. I can write an answer and I'll prefix it with "probably don't do this, but if you must...". Not a fun position to be in.

Comment: I'm not sure it's *that* uncommon.  The QA team often isn't allowed to mess with the DOM, and they have to select based on what they have.  Sometimes you have two elements (`UL`s or anything else) which are indistinguishable except for their number of children (eg. a normal element has one child, but an element with an error message has two children), and you want to select the element with N children.  Thanks to your help, anyone in that situation now has two options to select that element :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath is discouraged in Playwright, but the following locator seems to meet your needs:

```js
await page.locator("xpath=//ul[count(li)=2]")
```

Variants like `"//ul[count(li) >= 2]"` and `"//ul[count(li)=2][2]"` are possible.

This can be done without XPath, but it pretty much amounts to the same thing (selecting using a count), so I don't think this makes the locator better practice. Here's a complete example:

```js
const playwright = require("playwright"); // ^1.39.0

const html = `
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await playwright.firefox.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const ul = page.locator("ul", {
    has: page.locator("li:nth-child(2)"),
    hasNot: page.locator("li:nth-child(3)"),
  });
  console.log(await ul.textContent()); // => One Two
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

See also [Can CSS detect the number of children an element has?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720931/can-css-detect-the-number-of-children-an-element-has)

Comment: Yeah, XPath definitely feels like a method of last resort.  I'll hold off on accepting for a little bit in hope that there's a more "Playwright-esque" solution ... but if XPath is only way, then it's the only way.  Either way, thanks!

Comment: Sure, I don't love the answer either. I bet you could chain a few locators with `.and` and use `nth` and `:not()` to ensure there's two but not three `<li>` elements within a `<ul>`, but this feels pretty acrobatic to try to avoid the relatively straightforward XPath.

Comment: LOL at the `has`/`hasNot` solution.  Gotta love Playwright sometimes ...