# Select nth-child across multiple parents

Tags: css, parent-child, css-selectors

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="foo">
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>three</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>four</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I wish to style "one" and "three".

However, the markup could also be:

```
<div class="foo">
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>four</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've tried using the following CSS:

```
.foo li:nth-child(1),
.foo li:nth-child(3)
{
    color:red;
}
```

However, as expected, this is styling the first child of each `ul`. *(Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hTfVu/)*

How can I change my CSS so that I can target the 1st and 3rd `li` belonging to `.foo`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't do that with CSS selectors alone. `:nth-child()` and sibling combinators are limited to children/siblings sharing the same parent only, as implied by their names, and CSS selectors cannot account for such variations in parent-child structure, nor is there anything like an `:nth-grandchild()` selector (even [`:nth-match()` from Selectors 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#the-nth-match-pseudo) limits itself to elements sharing the same parent only).

Of course, this is trivial when using Javascript, for example with a library like jQuery: `$('.foo li:eq(0), .foo li:eq(2)')` Otherwise you'll have to mark the first and third `li` elements explicitly using classes or IDs, and then select them.

Answer (score -9):

You could use the even and odd selectors.

```
li:nth-child(odd) {
  color: red;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with the question.

Comment: The 1st and 3rd child are odd, using the li:nth-child(odd) would allow you to target just those two. Nevermind, I see it now. Sorry.

Comment: except the question is about selecting children with different parents.