# Select odd children with a specific class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Using CSS, I would like to select the odd children that a specific class. For example in the following html, I would like to select the div's containing "Child B 1" and "Child B 3":

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child a">
    Child A
  </div>
  <div class="child b">
    Child B 1
  </div>
  <div class="child b">
    Child B 2
  </div>
  <div class="child b">
    Child B 3
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried

```
.parent .b:nth-of-type(odd) {
  color:blue;
}
```

and

```
.parent .b:nth-child(odd) {
  color:blue;
}
```

but these both select "Child B 2" because it is an odd child of the parent class with the b class.

Is this possible? If so, what is the proper CSS selector?

Comment: Do not base nth selectors on class, nth depends on the parent, position among it's siblings, and tag.

Comment: nth-child is 1-based, which makes the first and third child "Child A" and "Child B 2" respectively.

Answer (score 0):

pretty close

see example below
and also https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

```css
.parent :nth-child(even) {
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child a">
    Child A
  </div>
  <div class="child b">
    Child B 1
  </div>
  <div class="child b">
    Child B 2
  </div>
  <div class="child b">
    Child B 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is that you can't do this with just CSS alone. It can be done quite easily if you add JavaScript or jQuery.  See more detailed answer here:

[Select nth-child across multiple parents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652543/select-nth-child-across-multiple-parents)

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear. I have other instances where it is just 

`<div class="parent">
  <div class="child b">
    Child B 1
  </div>
  <div class="child b">
    Child B 2
  </div>
  <div class="child b">
    Child B 3
  </div>
</div>` 

and I still need Child B 1 and Child B 3 to be selected because the html is rendered dynamically

Answer (score -1):

Just like he said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40430112/2593877), you can't do it with css alone.

I would suggest then, how ever you are dynamically creating these elements, every other one add a class to it and then in css select that class and apply the properties to it

```css
div.parent > div.child.b.odd {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h2>First</h2>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child a">
    Child A
  </div>
  <div class="child b odd">
    Child B 1
  </div>
  <div class="child b">
    Child B 2
  </div>
  <div class="child b odd">
    Child B 3
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<h2>Other</h2>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child b odd">
    Child B 1
  </div>
  <div class="child b">
    Child B 2
  </div>
  <div class="child b odd">
    Child B 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "the index of the first child is 1." - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp

Comment: Yeah so  `div.child.a` is 1 which is odd and the first `div.child.b` is 2 which is even, so the OP really wants to select the even child elements

Comment: I think the OP wants to select the odd ones among all elements of class `b`. Accordingly B1 would be the 1st element, B3 the 3rd.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40430058/select-odd-children-with-a-specific-class/40430117?noredirect=1#comment68108741_40430112