# Target outer div based on class of inner a

Tags: css, outer-join

Say I have something like this:

```
<div class="entry">
   <a class="click" href="http://domain.com">Some link</a>
</div>

<div class="entry">
   <a class="unclick" href="http://domain.com">Some link</a>
</div>
```

How would I target the entire contents of a .entry surrounding an a.click, without affecting the .entry surrounding of an a.unclick

I want to hide the outer div if the link has a class of "click".

EDIT: I need to do this without resorting to javascript, only CSS and HTML.

Comment: with CSS alone? jQuery yes. CSS perhaps not.

Comment: You can't ([yet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.relatedTarget)) CSS to style a parent based on its descendents.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apply CSS styles to an element depending on its child elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326499/apply-css-styles-to-an-element-depending-on-its-child-elements)