# Is it possible to select only li element containing a element with class with CSS

Tags: css

I have a simple menu styled with css.

```
<ul>
    <li> <a href="#">1</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#" class="active">2</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">3</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">4</a> </li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to apply specific style to li element, containing a with active class.

I've tryed something like this:

```
#container > ul > li a.active < li {
    custom: style;
}
```

Comment: Nope, not possible in CSS at the moment.

Comment: Try giving the `li` the `active` class. The only other way would involve JS which does not seem right for styling...

Comment: that's sad, thanks for answers

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with CSS. Though this can be achieved with scripting.

Similar question here.

[Apply CSS styles to an element depending on its child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326499/apply-css-styles-to-an-element-depending-on-its-child-elements)

Answer (score 1):

No, selectors can't match in reverse. In such circumstances the best approach is to simplify the matter.

`A` elements can be styled as block level elements, so simply push down whatever styles you had on the parent `LI` to the `A` elements. You already have your specific selector `a.active`, that should be distinct enough that you can style them appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

```
#container ul li a.active{ yourstyle:styleproperties;}
```

or I think you may want to do like this

```
#container ul li a:active{ yourstyle:styleproperties;}
```

if you want dynamically add class to element you can use javascript and jquery

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

```
$("#container ul li a").addClass("active");
```

and for parent(this class will be added for li element which is parent to a.active element)

```
$('#container ul li a.active').parent().addClass("active");
```

there is already similar topic [Target outer div based on class of inner a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782487/target-outer-div-based-on-class-of-inner-a?lq=1)

Comment: Sorry but he wants the container that has the `a.active` to have the style. So the style should apply on the `li` element that has the child `a.active`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ul li a.active{ color:green;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vloxxity/VZgQx/

Edit:
i've read your comment,
this is only possible if you mark the li with a active class.