# Is it possible to select body as a parent element?

Tags: css

I need to style body tag differently based on another element’s class that is set dynamically on load. Is it possible to select body as a parent element of another element without using JS?

Under condition #1 the page might look like this:

```
<body>
…
    <div class=”first-version”>…</div>
…
</body>
```

Under condition #2 the page might look like this - different class on div:

```
<body>
…
    <div class=”second-version”>…</div>
…
</body>
```

Pseudocode, this doesn’t work but gives you an idea what I’m trying to do (create a theme of sorts):

```
body[contains div.first-version] {
    margin:100px;
}
body[contains div.second-version] {
    margin:200px;
}
```

Comment: why don't you give the body tags an ID?

Comment: What do u intent to ask???? Question Not Clear.

Comment: I think you would like to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326499/apply-css-styles-to-an-element-depending-on-its-child-elements

Comment: Multiple body tags? But...why?

Comment: It's not multiple body tags - just 2 versions of how page might render. The class on div is rendered dynamically based on JSON page config.

Comment: Assigning body tag an id wouldn't make it any easier. You still need to somehow assign 2 different styles to the body tag based on the style of the child element.

Comment: if its not multiple body tags then you can always select it directly.

Comment: I know I can select it directly but I need to assign a different style to body tag based on another elements style. If div has style 1 then body should have style A, if div has style 2 than body should have style B.

Comment: If I understood correctly you want to set style of the body depending on the class of a div contained inside the body itself with pure CSS. I'm afraid that isn't possible since [there are no parent selectors on CSS](http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/), you would need to use JavaScript to navigate upwards. The `:root` pseudo-class you're using will not work with another selector preceding it. It will always be the `<html>` element.

Comment: @bostero2 - thanks. Yeah, I tried :root, it actually works to select body (:root body) but you're right you can't precede it with anything. I guess I'll use JS then.

Answer (score 0):

Use different classes for the body styling and you SHOULD use Javascript.

Comment: Why SHOULD someone use javascript?

Comment: he should use it in this case, he is creating different styling (themes)

Comment: @nasserui - you are right, I guess I should look at this as creating different themes.

Comment: Are you saying I can't just use jQuery without assigning a class or id to body? This wouldn't work? $('body').has('div.first-version').css('margin', '100px');

Answer (score 0):

Try this template:

HTML

```
<body id="the_body">
<input id="template_1" value="Template 1" type="button"/>
<input id="template_2" value="Template 2" type="button"/>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.template_1{
    color:red;
}
.template_2{
    color:blue;
}
```

JS (use jQuery):

```
$(function() {
      $("#template_1").click( function()
           {
             $("#the_body").html("<p class='template_1'>template 1</p>");
           }
      );
    $("#template_2").click( function()
           {
             $("#the_body").html("<p class='template_2'>template 2</p>");
           }
      );
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b9ytss4L/2/)**

Comment: Thank you. This is closer to what I need but not exactly. And I'm not sure why you need to assign id to body. Why can't it be just:
    $("body").html("<p class='template_2'>template 2</p>");

Comment: <body> and </body> tag only can show up 1 time. So, give them ID so that you can call them in which condition u need.

Replace my <p class='template_x'>template x</p> line with your own HTML codes based on body template(s).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks everyone for your help. That was very fast, I didn't expect this. Sorry if question wasn't clear. (This is my first time posting a question Stack Overflow).

It looks like pure CSS solution is not possible in this case and I should just use jQuery. Michael Marr posted the link to the jQuery solution that I'm going to use:

[Apply CSS styles to an element depending on its child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326499/apply-css-styles-to-an-element-depending-on-its-child-elements)

Comment: css doesn't have a parent selector.

Comment: zulhfreelancer - It didn't really. The answer that helped me was in the comments to my original question. I explained it in my own answer.