# Edit CSS on a div based on the content inside

Tags: html, css

I have two div's one with span that have text, and second with image.

So to the first div (draggableTemplate) with image I need set CSS with padding:0

and to the second div(draggableTemplate) with text I need set CSS with padding:10%

```
<div class="draggableTemplate">
    <img src="images/logo-blue.png" >
</div>

<div class="draggableTemplate">
    <span> Hello world...  </span>
</div>
```

I need something like this:

```
.draggableTemplate has: child(img) {
    //that have img child
    padding:0;
}

.draggableTemplate  has: child(span){
    //that have span
    padding:10%;
}
```

I need to set css to **parent** that have image inside and difrante css for parent with span inside

Set css to **PARENT** not child

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply CSS styles to an element depending on its child elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326499/apply-css-styles-to-an-element-depending-on-its-child-elements)

Comment: their is no way available in CSS where you can select parent based on their child. that "has:" selector is still in editor draft may available in Selectors Level 4. you can use jQuery to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you **cannot** select `parent` of specific `child` with CSS .

one way to do this is to use JQ with, for example, function `has()`

see **here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/zvtp5dd0/1/)**

JQ :

```
$(".draggableTemplate").has("img").css({"padding":"0"});
$(".draggableTemplate").has("span").css({"padding":"10%"});
```

or like this : **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/zvtp5dd0/2/)**

```
$(".draggableTemplate").has("img").addClass("has_img")
$(".draggableTemplate").has("span").addClass("has_span")
```

with CSS

```
.has_img{
  padding:0;
}
.has_span{
  padding:10%;
}
```

there are a number of ways to do this just **NOT** with only CSS

Comment: "only way to do this is to use JQ" -- that's incredibly false. You don't need jQuery in order to do this with javascript.

Comment: Yeah. You are right. Wanted to say that you cannot do thia with css