# Style an element only when there is no h1 sibling element

Tags: css, sass

I have two sets of markup on my page:

```
<div class="row">
    <div>Some random div(s)</div>
    <table></table>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="row">
    <div>Some random div(s)</div>
    <h1>Table Title</h1>
    <table></table>
</div>
```

I would like to apply `margin-top` and some other CSS customizations to **`div.row > table` when there is no `h1` in `div.row`**.
For example, in the above markup the first `table` would be styled but the second would not.

I can't find a convenient way to setup a rule for that set of conditions. I'm quite new to SASS and don't want to have to add a specific class to the `table` element.

Do you have any tips on what to do to achieve this?

Comment: Does the `h1` always come directly before the `table`?

Comment: When there is a h1 yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are looking to style a `table` which always appears *after* an adjacent `h1` element this is achievable in CSS by using a combination of the `:not()` and next-sibling (`+`) selectors.

```
.row > :not(h1) + table
```

The rule will match any `table` element which *is* directly preceded by an element which *is not* an `h1` which *is* an immediate child of an element with the class `.row`.

```css
.row > :not(h1) + table {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div>Some random div(s)</div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>This will match the rule</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div>Some random div(s)</div>
  <h1>Table Title</h1>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>This will not match the rule</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it does the job as expected. Didn't thought about `:not()` selector.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

SASS ultimately compiles down to CSS, and according to the CSS rules, such a selector is **not** possible. You will have to do it via scripting (javascript, jQuery). There have been a lot of questions about this. Check these references:

[Apply CSS styles to an element depending on its child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326499/apply-css-styles-to-an-element-depending-on-its-child-elements)

[CSS selector for “foo that contains bar”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000582/css-selector-for-foo-that-contains-bar)

[Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Finally, check [this link](https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors) for the reasons **why** we don't have the parent selector option.