# How can an element be styled based on the class of a child

Tags: css

I have the following HTML:

I cannot apply any JavaScript, but I can edit the CSS. I can edit the HTML of the  only

```
<div>
  <div>
    <span class="something">Styled content</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    Unstyled content
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to style (specifically, display:none;) the unstyled content as well.

I don't mind if I style the whole containing div or just the divs with content.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326499/apply-css-styles-to-an-element-depending-on-its-child-elements

Comment: A parent selector would work, but I wondered if there was some way to style a div which comes after the parent of a style.  

Perhaps 
    (div>.something)+div

I know that wouldn't work, but perhaps something similar?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in simply css you can read the answers here: [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

You can do it in jquery though:

```
$(".something").parent().css("display","none");
```

or with javascript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("something")[0].parentNode.style.display= "none";
```